# Volatile vs Static in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, static, volatile

Is it correct to say that `static` means one copy of the value for all objects and `volatile` means one copy of the value for all threads?

Anyway a `static` variable value is also going to be one value for all threads, then why should we go for `volatile`?

Comment: Official explanation of volatile: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile

Answer (score 399, accepted):

Declaring a **static** variable in Java, means that there will be only one copy, no matter how many objects of the class are created. The variable will be accessible even with no `Objects` created at all. However, threads may have locally cached values of it.

When a variable is **volatile** and not **static**, there will be one variable for each `Object`. So, on the surface it seems there is no difference from a normal variable but totally different from **static**. However, even with `Object` fields, a thread may cache a variable value locally.

This means that if two threads update a variable of the same Object concurrently, and the variable is not declared volatile, there could be a case in which one of the thread has in cache an old value.

Even if you access a **static** value through multiple threads, each thread can have its local cached copy! To avoid this you can declare the variable as **static volatile** and this will force the thread to read each time the global value.

However, **volatile** is not a substitute for proper synchronisation!
For instance:

```
private static volatile int counter = 0;

private void concurrentMethodWrong() {
  counter = counter + 5;
  //do something
  counter = counter - 5;
}
```

Executing `concurrentMethodWrong` concurrently many times may lead to a final value of counter different from zero!
To solve the problem, you have to implement a lock:

```
private static final Object counterLock = new Object();

private static volatile int counter = 0;

private void concurrentMethodRight() {
  synchronized (counterLock) {
    counter = counter + 5;
  }
  //do something
  synchronized (counterLock) {
    counter = counter - 5;
  }
}
```

Or use the [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class.

Comment: So does it means ALWAYS it's necessary to set volatile?

Comment: The volatile modifier guarantees that any thread that reads a field will see the most recently written value, so it's necessary if the variable is shared among multiple thread and you need this feature, it depends on your use case.

Comment: What is the cache when you say "locally cached"? CPU cache, some kind of JVM cache?

Comment: @mertinan yes, the variable can be in a cache nearer to the processor or core. See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html for more details.

Comment: 'volatile' does ***not*** imply 'one variable per object'. Absence of 'static' does that. -1 for failing to clear up this elementary misconception on the part of the OP.

Comment: @EJP I thought that the sentence "Declaring a variable as volatile, there will be one variable for each Object. So on the surface it seems there is no difference from a normal variable" was explaining that, I've added *and not static*, feel free to edit the article and improve the wording to make that clearer.

Comment: If volatile doesn't automatically impose proper synchronization then why use it? We could make any regular variable synchronized. What's the purpose of volatile?

Comment: @stivlo I don't see how the counter can be different from zero. Each thread that calls the concurrentMethodWrong will increment and decrement by 5. So the effective work done by each thread is zero (0). Am I missing something fundamental in my reasoning?

Comment: @stivlo I see, but I can't explain it. Well, guess I have to read these posts a few more times.

Comment: @filip counter = counter + 5 is not an atomic operation. The thread could be switched in the middle of it, i.e. after reading counter but before adding 5.

Comment: @stivlo Yes, of course. I get it know, thank you for your time.

Comment: @ernesto volatile is sufficient if only one thread ever writes to the volatile variable.  If two or more threads can write to it, then you need synchronized too.

Comment: @John Hascall this is not quite right – it is all about atomicity and not how many thread write. Even if two or more threads write to a volatile variable it doesn't need to be synchronized if they do not need the variable’s previous value to determine its new value – volatile make writing to a variable of any type atomic. Only reading and writing by multiple threads (like in a counter example) makes synchronization necessary.

Answer (score 298):

Difference Between Static and Volatile :

**Static Variable**:  If two Threads(suppose `t1` and `t2`) are accessing the same object and updating a variable which is declared as static   then  it means `t1` and `t2` can make their own local copy  of the same object(including static variables) in their respective cache, so update made by `t1` to the static variable in its local cache wont reflect  in the static variable for `t2` cache .

Static variables are used in the **context of Object** where update made by one object would reflect in all the other objects of the same class **but not in  the context of Thread** where update of one thread to the static variable will reflect the changes immediately to all the threads (in their local cache).

**Volatile variable**: If two Threads(suppose `t1` and `t2`) are accessing the same object and updating a variable which is declared as volatile   then  it means `t1` and `t2` can make their own local cache  of the Object **except the variable which is declared as a volatile** . So the volatile variable will have only one main copy which will be updated by different threads and update made by one thread to the volatile variable will immediately reflect to the other Thread.

Comment: Hello @Som, Please correct me if I am wrong. But don't you think the statement "**but not in the context of Thread where update of one thread to the static variable will reflect the changes immediately to all the threads (in their local cache).**" should be "but not in the context of Thread where update of one thread to the static variable will **<<NOT>>** reflect the changes immediately to all the threads (in their local cache)."

Comment: @Jaikrat Yes that was very confusing for me.  My understanding is that you're right and that this answer is wrong, as written.  I would also like to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jaikrat Threads don't cache the static variables though but, do refer to the updated static variables .

Comment: @Som Then would you like to correct the para and remove **but not in the context of Thread**. Thats very confusing. Thanks

Comment: Sadly, this answer is incorrect. On modern CPUs, even a `volatile` variable can be shared among distinct CPU caches. This presents no problem because the cache negotiates exclusive ownership of the cache line prior to modify it.

Comment: Hello @Som,  Can Threads cache AtomicInteger variable as well like normal primitives ?

Answer (score 49):

In addition to other answers, I would like to add one image for it(pic makes easy to understand)

[image]

`static` variables may be cached for individual threads. In multi-threaded environment **if one thread modifies its cached data, that may not reflect for other threads as they have a copy** of it.

`volatile` declaration makes sure that threads **won't cache the data and uses the shared copy** only.

[image source](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/volatile-vs-static-in-java/)

Comment: static variables are shared among objects under a thread? This should read static variables are shared among objects all objects regardless of threads.

Comment: "volatile variables are shared among multiple threads(so objects as well)."

Volatile does not change how variables are shared among multiple threads or objects. It changes how the runtime is allowed to cache the value.

Comment: Your comment about static variables also applies to non static and the "will be cached" and "will not reflect" should probably be rephrased "may be cached" and "may not reflect".

Comment: I was very confused. this picture cleared all my questions!

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Answer (score 7):

I think `static` and `volatile` have no relation at all. I suggest you read java tutorial to understand [Atomic Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), and why use atomic access, understand what is [interleaved](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html), you will find answer.

Answer (score 5):

In simple terms,

1. [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) : `static` variables are associated with the ***class***, rather than with any ***object***. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory
2. [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html): This keyword is applicable to both ***class*** and ***instance*** variables.

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads

Have a look at this [article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html) by `Javin Paul`  to understand volatile variables in a better way.

[image]

In absence of `volatile` keyword, the value of variable in each thread's stack may be different. By making the variable as `volatile`, all threads will get same value in their working memory and memory consistency errors have been avoided.

Here the term `variable` can be either `static` (class) variable or `instance` (object) variable.

Regarding your query :

> Anyway a static variable value is also going to be one value for all threads, then why should we go for volatile?

If I need `instance` variable in my application, I can't use `static` variable. Even in case of `static` variable, consistency is not guaranteed due to Thread cache as shown in the diagram.

Using `volatile` variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads.

> What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change => ***memory consistency errors are still possible with volatile variables***. To avoid side effects, you have to use synchronized variables. But there is a better solution in java.

***Using simple atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing these variables through synchronized code***

Some of the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package provide atomic methods that do not rely on synchronization.

Refer to this [high level concurrency control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) article for more details.

Especially have a look at [Atomic variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html).

Related SE questions:

[Volatile Vs Atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744508/volatile-vs-atomic)

[Volatile boolean vs AtomicBoolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786825/volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean)

[Difference between volatile and synchronized in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java/34355995#34355995)

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. I knew what is the `volatile` earlier, but, this answer clarifies a lot for me why do I still need to use `volatile` with the `static` variable.

Comment: volatile: This keyword is applicable to both class and instance variables. The statement you said above is incorrect regarding applicable to class. only two key words that applicable to variable is volatile and transient. so volatile wont applicable for class.

Comment: volatile is applicable to class ( static ) variables.  Check out for Double locked singleton links in google and you can find that your understanding is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093735/double-checked-locking-in-singleton

Comment: private static volatile is valid declaration.

Answer (score 2):

It is incorrect to say that static means one copy of the value for all objects because static means there will be only **one copy for each classloader that loads the containing class**.

The Java volatile keyword means, that every read of a volatile variable will be read from the computer's main memory, and not from the CPU cache, and that every write to a volatile variable will be written to main memory, and not just to the CPU cache.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure static variables are cached in thread local memory or NOT. But when I executed two threads(T1,T2) accessing same object(obj) and when update made by T1 thread to static variable it got reflected in T2.

Answer (score -1):

volatile variable value access will be direct from main memory. It should be used only in multi-threading environment.
static variable will be loaded one time. If its used in single thread environment, even if the copy of the variable will be updated and there will be no harm accessing it as there is only one thread.

Now if static variable is used in multi-threading environment then there will be issues if one expects desired result from it. As each thread has their own copy then any increment or decrement on static variable from one thread may not reflect in another thread.

if one expects desired results from static variable then use volatile with static in multi-threading then everything will be resolved.

Answer (score -2):

If we declare a variable as static, there will be only one copy of the variable.
So, whenever different threads access that variable, there will be only one final value for the variable(since there is only one memory location allocated for the variable).

If a variable is declared as volatile, all threads will have their own copy of the variable but the value is taken from the main memory.So, the value of the variable in all the threads will be the same.

So, in both cases, the main point is that the value of the variable is same across all threads.

Comment: *If a variable is declared as volatile, all threads will have their own copy of the variable but the value is taken from the main memory.* => **right.** *So, the value of the variable in all the threads will be the same.* => **wrong, each thread will use the same value for the same Object, but each Object will have its own copy.**