# What are Transient and Volatile Modifiers?

Tags: java, serialization, storage, modifier

Can someone explain what the `transient` and `volatile` modifiers mean in Java?

Comment: This was clearly not a question and this is a duplicate anyway (which is why I voted to close). See for example [Why does Java have transient variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables) and [When exactly do you use the volatile keyword in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488703/when-exactly-do-you-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java) (and the many others).

Comment: possible duplicate of [For what is used "volatile" ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430757/for-what-is-used-volatile)

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, equivalent to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private/215505

Answer (score 166):

The `volatile` and `transient` modifiers can be applied to fields of classes<sup>1</sup> irrespective of field type.  Apart from that, they are unrelated.

The `transient` modifier tells the Java object serialization subsystem to exclude the field when serializing an instance of the class.  When the object is then deserialized, the field will be initialized to the default value; i.e. `null` for a reference type, and zero or `false` for a primitive type. Note that the JLS (see [8.3.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.3)) does not say what `transient` means, but defers to the [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). Other serialization mechanisms *may* pay attention to a field's `transient`-ness.   Or they may ignore it.

(Note that the JLS permits a `static` field to be declared as `transient`.  This combination doesn't make sense for Java Object Serialization, since it doesn't serialize statics anyway.  However, it could make sense in other contexts, so there is some justification for not forbidding it outright.)

The `volatile` modifier tells the JVM that writes to the field should always be synchronously flushed to memory, and that reads of the field should always read from memory<sup>2</sup>.  This means that fields marked as volatile can be safely accessed and updated in a multi-thread application without using native or standard library-based synchronization.  Similarly, reads and writes to volatile fields are atomic. (This does not apply to >>non-volatile<< `long` or `double` fields, which may be subject to "word tearing" on some JVMs.)  The relevant parts of the JLS are [8.3.1.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.4), [17.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4) and [17.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.7).

---

<sup>1 - But not to local variables or parameters.

2 - This explanation is intentionally informal and simplified.  There are additional implications for the visibility of non-volatile writes that occur before the volatile write, for example.  See the JLS Chapter 17 (Memory Model) references linked above for a precise, formal, and detailed specification of `volatile` semantics.  Note that the JMM specification is in terms of modeled behavior, and is agnostic of how that behavior is implemented at the platform level.</sup>

Answer (score 11):

`volatile` and `transient` keywords

1) `transient` keyword is used along with instance variables to exclude them from serialization process. If a field  is `transient` its value will not be persisted.

On the other hand, `volatile` keyword is used to mark a Java variable as "being stored in main memory".

Every read of a `volatile` variable will be read from the computer's main memory, and not from the CPU cache, and that every write to a `volatile` variable will be written to main memory, and not just to the CPU cache.

2) `transient` keyword cannot be used along with `static` keyword but `volatile` can be used along with `static`.

3) `transient` variables are initialized with default value during de-serialization and there assignment or restoration of value has to be handled by application code.

For more information, see my blog:
http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2015/07/difference-between-volatile-and.html

Comment: The reason the `transient` variable can't be used along with the `static` keyword is
static variables belong to a class and not to any individual instance. The concept of serialization is concerned with the object’s current state. Only data associated with a specific instance of a class is serialized, therefore static member fields are ignored during serialization

Comment: Actually, the JLS permits `static` and `transient` to be used together.  The problem is it makes little sense, because typical serialization mechanisms don't persist statics anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Volatile means other threads can edit that particular variable. So the compiler allows access to them.

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

Transient means that when you serialize an object, it will return its default value on de-serialization

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/2

Comment: "So the compiler allows access to them." Your sentence suggest that threads don't have access by default. Now I read the link and the other answer I understand: compiler don't do any kind of thread-specific intermediate storage of the variable so other threads can see the changes inmediatly.

Comment: I got the C use of volatile and java use of volatile confused. I meant the compiler ensures it has access to the actaul value of the field rather then a cached value.

Answer (score 2):

Transient :

**First need to know where it needed how it bridge the gap.**

1) An Access modifier transient is only applicable to variable component only. 
It will not used with method or class.

2) Transient keyword cannot be used along with static keyword.

3) What is serialization and where it is used?
Serialization is the process of making the object's state persistent. That means the state of the object is converted into a stream of bytes to be used for persisting (e.g. storing bytes in a file) or transferring (e.g. sending bytes across a network). In the same way, we can use the deserialization to bring back the object's state from bytes. This is one of the important concepts in Java programming because serialization is mostly used in networking programming. The objects that need to be transmitted through the network have to be converted into bytes. 
Before understanding the transient keyword, one has to understand the concept of serialization. If the reader knows about serialization, please skip the first point.

Note 1) Transient is mainly use for serialzation process. 
For that the class must implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
All of the fields in the class must be serializable. If a field is not serializable, it must be marked transient.

Note 2) When deserialized process taken place they get set to the default value - zero, false, or null as per type constraint.

Note 3) Transient keyword and its purpose?
A field which is declare with transient modifier it will not take part in serialized process.
When an object is serialized(saved in any state), the values of its transient fields are ignored in the serial representation, while the field other than transient fields will take part in serialization process. That is the main purpose of the transient keyword.

Comment: This should have been top-voted! Nicely explained.

Comment: Nit-pick: neither `transient` or `volatile` are **access** modifiers.  The access modifiers are `public`, `protected` and `private`.