# Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm trying to learn Gson and I'm struggling with field exclusion. Here are my classes

```
public class Student {    
  private Long                id;
  private String              firstName        = "Philip";
  private String              middleName       = "J.";
  private String              initials         = "P.F";
  private String              lastName         = "Fry";
  private Country             country;
  private Country             countryOfBirth;
}

public class Country {    
  private Long                id;
  private String              name;
  private Object              other;
}
```

I can use the GsonBuilder and add an ExclusionStrategy for a field name like `firstName` or `country` but I can't seem to manage to exclude properties of certain fields like `country.name`.

Using the method `public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fa)`, FieldAttributes doesn't contain enough information to match the field with a filter like `country.name`.

P.S: I want to avoid annotations since I want to improve on this and use RegEx to filter fields out.

**Edit**: I'm trying to see if it's possible to emulate the behavior of [Struts2 JSON plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin)

using Gson

```
<interceptor-ref name="json">
  <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
  <param name="excludeProperties">
    login.password,
    studentList.*\.sin
  </param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

**Edit:**
    I reopened the question with the following addition:

I added a second field with the same type to futher clarify this problem. Basically I want to exclude `country.name` but not `countrOfBirth.name`. I also don't want to exclude Country as a type.
So the types are the same it's the actual place in the object graph that I want to pinpoint and exclude.

Comment: Still as of version 2.2 I still can't specify a path to field to exclude. http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/ feels like a good alternative.

Comment: Have a look on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243035/6413377) to a quite a similar question. It is based on creating a custom `JsonSerializer` for some type -`Country` in your case- for which then is applied an `ExclusionStrategy` which decides what fields to serialize.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544919/what-are-transient-and-volatile-modifiers

Answer (score 672):

Any fields you don't want serialized in general you should use the "transient" modifier, and this also applies to json serializers (at least it does to a few that I have used, including gson).

If you don't want name to show up in the serialized json give it a transient keyword, eg:

```
private transient String name;
```

[More details in the Gson documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects)

Comment: it's almost the same thing as an exclusion annotation as in it applies to all instances of that class. I wanted runtime dynamic exclusion. I some cases I want some fields excluded in order to provide a lighter/restricted response and in others I want the full object serialized

Comment: One thing to note is that transient effects both serialization and deserialization. It will also emit the value from been serialized into the object, even if it is present in the JSON.

Comment: Great way of exclusion. It helps me to generate JSON configs from POJOs to use with TickTick.

Comment: The problem with using `transient` instead of `@Expose` is that you still have to mock up a POJO on your client with all fields that could possibly come in.  In the case of a back-end API that might be shared among projects, this could be problematic in case additional fields are added.  Essentially it is whitelisting vs blacklisting of the fields.

Comment: This approach didn't work for me, as it not only excluded the field from gson serialization, but excluded the field from internal app serialization (using Serializable interface).

Comment: This is a very dangerous approach: as @pkk said, `transient` not only excludes the field from the serialization, but also doesn't let JPA to treat the field (it will not be automatically managed).

Comment: You might want to try alternative solution presented in my answer using custom "exclusion" annotation, that works "like" transient modifier, but is limited to Gson parser scope.

Comment: transient prevents SERIALIZATION and DESERIALIZATION of a field. This does not match my needs.

Comment: It does not work when the field must be persisted in the database. For example, hibernate would ignore transient fields too.

Comment: How about if this field is to be saved in database? This solution will break

Comment: transient, final, static fields are Not allowed from >v0.88

Comment: This should not be used as it restrict field to box and unbox from all functionality. You even can not send transient field in serializable/parcelable i.e. within activity or fragment.

Comment: transient has a specific semantics in Java. You shouldn't use it unless you want your field to really be transient.

Comment: @ProfMo and others, the transient keyword is used to prevent data from being serialized/deserialized. Since converting an object to JSON is a form of serialization, I believe it is used properly.

Comment: Why does Google always want to mess with your private parts? This is scary, I have a huge project (Android front end and JEE back end) that I used Gson in heavily. And there I was, thinking Gson would just ignore the private parts since JAXRS serializers do that by default. F***** hell man. Good thing it was over SSL. Now I have to refactor.

Comment: use @Transient in Kotlin

Answer (score 327):

Nishant provided a good solution, but there's an easier way. Simply mark the desired fields with the @Expose annotation, such as:

```
@Expose private Long id;
```

Leave out any fields that you do not want to serialize. Then just create your Gson object this way:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Comment: Is it possible to have something like "notExpose" and only ignore those for the case where all but one field must be serialized and adding annotations to all of them is redundant?

Comment: @DaSh I recently had such a scenario. It was very easy to write a custom ExclusionStrategy which did exactly that. See Nishant's answer. The only problem was to include a bunch of container classes and fiddle with skipclass vs skipfield (fields can be classes...)

Comment: @DaSh [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17733569/657111) below does exactly that.

Comment: What a great solution. I was running into a scenario where I want a field serialized to disk but to be ignored when sending it to a server via gson. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Danlil You should be able to use @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)

Comment: Can I somehow let GSON know to read a field, but not write it?
I updated a classe's fields, so I want the "old" fields to be read but only the new ones should be written...?

Comment: @DaniilShevelev Thats exactly what i was also looking for and i implemented below. --------

public class DeserializationExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy{
 @ Override
 public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
  Collection<Annotation> annotations = f.getAnnotations();
  if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(annotations)) {
   for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
    if (annotation instanceof Expose) {
     return true;
    }
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
 @ Override
 public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
  return false;
 }
}

Comment: Q: `how to ... without annotations`. A: `use annotation...` http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/010/277/genius.jpg

Comment: what it bad here is that you are forced to use `GsonBuilder` for this, so if you are in control of the code that serializes that's fine, but if someone else serializes a hierarchy of objects, without ever knowing that some field was not meant to be serialized and will use a plain `new Gson()...`

Answer (score 250):

So, you want to **exclude** `firstName` and `country.name`. Here is what your `ExclusionStrategy` should look like

```
    public class TestExclStrat implements ExclusionStrategy {

        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {

            return (f.getDeclaringClass() == Student.class && f.getName().equals("firstName"))||
            (f.getDeclaringClass() == Country.class && f.getName().equals("name"));
        }

    }
```

If you see closely it returns `true` for `Student.firstName` and `Country.name`, which is what you want to exclude.

You need to apply this `ExclusionStrategy` like this,

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new TestExclStrat())
        //.serializeNulls() <-- uncomment to serialize NULL fields as well
        .create();
    Student src = new Student();
    String json = gson.toJson(src);
    System.out.println(json);
```

This returns:

```
{ "middleName": "J.", "initials": "P.F", "lastName": "Fry", "country": { "id": 91}}
```

I assume the country object is initialized with `id = 91L` in student class.

---

You may get fancy. For example, you do not want to serialize any field that contains "name" string in its name. Do this:

```
public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
    return f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("name"); 
}
```

This will return:

```
{ "initials": "P.F", "country": { "id": 91 }}
```

---

**EDIT:** Added more info as requested.

This `ExclusionStrategy` will do the thing, but you need to pass "Fully Qualified Field Name". See below:

```
    public class TestExclStrat implements ExclusionStrategy {

        private Class<?> c;
        private String fieldName;
        public TestExclStrat(String fqfn) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            this.c = Class.forName(fqfn.substring(0, fqfn.lastIndexOf(".")));
            this.fieldName = fqfn.substring(fqfn.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        }
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {

            return (f.getDeclaringClass() == c && f.getName().equals(fieldName));
        }

    }
```

Here is how we can use it generically.

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new TestExclStrat("in.naishe.test.Country.name"))
        //.serializeNulls()
        .create();
    Student src = new Student();
    String json = gson.toJson(src);
    System.out.println(json);
```

It returns:

```
{ "firstName": "Philip" , "middleName": "J.", "initials": "P.F", "lastName": "Fry", "country": { "id": 91 }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What I want is to create an ExclusionStrategy that can take a string like `country.name` and only exlude the field `name` when serializing the field `country`. It should be generic enough to apply to every class that has a property named country of the Country class. I don't want to create an ExclusionStrategy for every class

Comment: @Liviu T. I have updated the answer. That takes generic approach. You may get even more creative, but I kept it elemental.

Comment: Ty for the update. What I;m trying to see if it's possible to know where in the object graph I am when the method it called so I can exclude some fields of country but not countryOfBirth(for example) so same class but different properties. I've edited my question to clarify what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Is there a way to exclude fields which has empty values?

Comment: I have the same question than @ykartal. How can I exclude empty fields?

Comment: you mean null value or empty string. Didn't get what do you mean by empty.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the preferred answer.  Unlike the other answers that currently have more votes, this solution does not require you to modify the bean class.   This is a huge plus.  What if someone else were using the same bean class, and you marked a field they wanted persisted as "transient"?

Comment: The answer is ideal, but GSON is not. The shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) is called for root level fields only. It can be easily checked by simple println(). Even more, @Expose works for root level only, too. It seems, GSON us useless for more complex work.

Comment: @user64141 while you are right, this is still not a solution. Imagine that you are in control of the code that serializes something and you indeed use `GsonBuilder`  for this; but now imagine the other side - someone serializing your Object *by accident* - it's a big hierarchy for example,  and does not even know  about your special  treatment of some fields, so it uses a plain `new Gson()...`. I don't see a way to achieve this

Answer (score 246):

After reading all available answers I found out, that most flexible, in my case, was to use custom `@Exclude` annotation. So, I implemented simple strategy for this (I didn't want to mark all fields using `@Expose` nor I wanted to use `transient` which conflicted with in app `Serializable` serialization) :

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Exclude {
}
```

Strategy:

```
public class AnnotationExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new AnnotationExclusionStrategy()).create();
```

Comment: As an additional note, if you want to use your exclusion strategy for only serialization or only deserialization, use: `addSerializationExclusionStrategy` or `addDeserializationExclusionStrategy` instead of `setExclusionStrategies`

Comment: Perfect! The transient solution doesn't work for me because I'm using Realm for DB and I want to exclude a field only from Gson, but not Realm (wich transient does)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To ignore null fields just change `f.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) != null` to `f.getAnnotation(Exclude.class) == null`

Comment: Excellent when you cannot use `transient` because of other libraries' needs. Thanks!

Comment: Also great for me because Android serializes my classes between activities, but I only want them excluded when I use GSON. This let's my app keep functioning the same way until it wants to wrap them up to send off to others.

Comment: any alternative for Moshi?

Answer (score 87):

I ran into this issue, in which I had a small number of fields I wanted to exclude only from serialization, so I developed a fairly simple solution that uses Gson's `@Expose` annotation with custom exclusion strategies.

The only built-in way to use `@Expose` is by setting `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`, but as the name indicates, fields without an explicit `@Expose` are ignored. As I only had a few fields I wanted to exclude, I found the prospect of adding the annotation to every field very cumbersome.

I effectively wanted the inverse, in which everything was included unless I explicitly used `@Expose` to exclude it. I used the following exclusion strategies to accomplish this:

```
new GsonBuilder()
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
                final Expose expose = fieldAttributes.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
                return expose != null && !expose.serialize();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
                final Expose expose = fieldAttributes.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
                return expose != null && !expose.deserialize();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .create();
```

Now I can easily exclude a few fields with `@Expose(serialize = false)` or `@Expose(deserialize = false)` annotations (note that the default value for both `@Expose` attributes is `true`). You can of course use `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)`, but that is more concisely accomplished by declaring the field `transient` instead (which does still take effect with these custom exclusion strategies).

Comment: For efficiency, I can see a case for using @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false) rather than transient.

Comment: @paiego Can you expand on that? I'm now many years removed from using Gson, and I don't understand why the annotation is more efficient than marking it transient.

Comment: Ahh, I made a mistake, thanks for catching this. I mistook volatile for transient.

(e.g. There is no caching and therefore no cache-coherency problem with volatile, but it's less performant)

Anyway, your code worked great!

Answer (score 18):

You can explore the json tree with gson.

Try something like this :

```
gson.toJsonTree(student).getAsJsonObject()
.get("country").getAsJsonObject().remove("name");
```

You can add some properties also :

```
gson.toJsonTree(student).getAsJsonObject().addProperty("isGoodStudent", false);
```

Tested with gson 2.2.4.

Comment: I wonder whether this is too much of a performance hit if you want to get rid of a complex property which has to be parsed before removal. Thoughts?

Comment: Definitely not a scalable solution, imagine all the headache you will need to go through if you change the structure of your object or add/remove stuff.

Answer (score 17):

I came up with a class factory to support this functionality. Pass in any combination of either fields or classes you want to exclude.

```
public class GsonFactory {

    public static Gson build(final List<String> fieldExclusions, final List<Class<?>> classExclusions) {
        GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
        b.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return fieldExclusions == null ? false : fieldExclusions.contains(f.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return classExclusions == null ? false : classExclusions.contains(clazz);
            }
        });
        return b.create();

    }
}
```

To use, create two lists (each is optional), and create your GSON object:

```
static {
 List<String> fieldExclusions = new ArrayList<String>();
 fieldExclusions.add("id");
 fieldExclusions.add("provider");
 fieldExclusions.add("products");

 List<Class<?>> classExclusions = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
 classExclusions.add(Product.class);
 GSON = GsonFactory.build(null, classExclusions);
}

private static final Gson GSON;

public String getSomeJson(){
    List<Provider> list = getEntitiesFromDatabase();
    return GSON.toJson(list);
}
```

Comment: Of course, this can be modified to look at the fully qualified name of the attribute and exclude that upon a match...

Comment: I'm doing below example . This is not working. Pls suggest
private static final Gson GSON;
 static {
  List<String> fieldExclusions = new ArrayList<String>();
  fieldExclusions.add("id");

  GSON = GsonFactory.build(fieldExclusions, null);
 }
 
 private static String getSomeJson() {
  String jsonStr = "[{\"id\":111,\"name\":\"praveen\",\"age\":16},{\"id\":222,\"name\":\"prashant\",\"age\":20}]";
  return jsonStr;
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String jsonStr = getSomeJson();
  System.out.println(GSON.toJson(jsonStr));
 }

Answer (score 16):

I solved this problem with custom annotations.
This is my "SkipSerialisation" Annotation class:

```
@Target (ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SkipSerialisation {

}
```

and this is my GsonBuilder:

```
gsonBuilder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {

  @Override public boolean shouldSkipField (FieldAttributes f) {

    return f.getAnnotation(SkipSerialisation.class) != null;

  }

  @Override public boolean shouldSkipClass (Class<?> clazz) {

    return false;
  }
});
```

Example :

```
public class User implements Serializable {

  public String firstName;

  public String lastName;

  @SkipSerialisation
  public String email;
}
```

Comment: Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization **without annotations**

Comment: You should also add `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` to your annotation.

Answer (score 14):

Kotlin's `@Transient`annotation also does the trick apparently.

```
data class Json(
    @field:SerializedName("serialized_field_1") val field1: String,
    @field:SerializedName("serialized_field_2") val field2: String,
    @Transient val field3: String
)
```

Output:

```
{"serialized_field_1":"VALUE1","serialized_field_2":"VALUE2"}
```

Answer (score 9):

Or can say whats fields not will expose with:

```
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT).create();
```

on your class on attribute:

```
private **transient** boolean nameAttribute;
```

Comment: Transient and static fields are excluded by default; there's no need to call `excludeFieldsWithModifiers()` for that.

Answer (score 9):

I used this strategy: 
i excluded every field which is **not** marked with **@SerializedName** annotation, i.e.:

```
public class Dummy {

    @SerializedName("VisibleValue")
    final String visibleValue;
    final String hiddenValue;

    public Dummy(String visibleValue, String hiddenValue) {
        this.visibleValue = visibleValue;
        this.hiddenValue = hiddenValue;
    }
}


public class SerializedNameOnlyStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class) == null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}


Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new SerializedNameOnlyStrategy())
                .create();

Dummy dummy = new Dummy("I will see this","I will not see this");
String json = gson.toJson(dummy);
```

It returns

> {"VisibleValue":"I will see this"}

Answer (score 7):

Another approach (especially useful if you need to make a decision to exclude a field at runtime) is to register a TypeAdapter with your gson instance. Example below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.registerTypeAdapter(BloodPressurePost.class, new BloodPressurePostSerializer())
```

In the case below, the server would expect one of two values but since they were both ints then gson would serialize them both. My goal was to omit any value that is zero (or less) from the json that is posted to the server.

```
public class BloodPressurePostSerializer implements JsonSerializer<BloodPressurePost> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(BloodPressurePost src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        if (src.systolic > 0) {
            jsonObject.addProperty("systolic", src.systolic);
        }

        if (src.diastolic > 0) {
            jsonObject.addProperty("diastolic", src.diastolic);
        }

        jsonObject.addProperty("units", src.units);

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in kotlin can use @Transient to ignore the field...  eg.

```
data class MyClass{
@Transient var  myVar: Boolean
//....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working just by putting the `@Expose` annotation, here my version that I use

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

In `Model` class:

```
@Expose
int number;

public class AdapterRestApi {
```

In the `Adapter` class:

```
public EndPointsApi connectRestApi() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(90000,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ConstantRestApi.ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit.create  (EndPointsApi.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Kotlin version

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
internal annotation class JsonSkip

class SkipFieldsStrategy : ExclusionStrategy {

    override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes): Boolean {
        return f.getAnnotation(JsonSkip::class.java) != null
    }
}
```

and how You can add this to Retrofit GSONConverterFactory:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(SkipFieldsStrategy())
                //.serializeNulls()
                //.setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG)
                //.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                //.setPrettyPrinting()
                //.registerTypeAdapter(Id.class, IdTypeAdapter())
                .create()
        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
```

Answer (score 1):

This what I always use:

The default behaviour implemented in Gson is that null object fields are ignored.

Means Gson object does not serialize fields with null values to JSON. If a field in a Java object is null, Gson excludes it.

You can use this function to convert some object to null or well set by your own

```
     /**
   * convert object to json
   */
  public String toJson(Object obj) {
    // Convert emtpy string and objects to null so we don't serialze them
    setEmtpyStringsAndObjectsToNull(obj);
    return gson.toJson(obj);
  }

  /**
   * Sets all empty strings and objects (all fields null) including sets to null.
   *
   * @param obj any object
   */
  public void setEmtpyStringsAndObjectsToNull(Object obj) {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      field.setAccessible(true);
      try {
        Object fieldObj = field.get(obj);
        if (fieldObj != null) {
          Class fieldType = field.getType();
          if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            if(fieldObj.equals("")) {
              field.set(obj, null);
            }
          } else if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Set.class)) {
            for (Object item : (Set) fieldObj) {
              setEmtpyStringsAndObjectsToNull(item);
            }
            boolean setFielToNull = true;
            for (Object item : (Set) field.get(obj)) {
              if(item != null) {
                setFielToNull = false;
                break;
              }
            }
            if(setFielToNull) {
              setFieldToNull(obj, field);
            }
          } else if (!isPrimitiveOrWrapper(fieldType)) {
            setEmtpyStringsAndObjectsToNull(fieldObj);
            boolean setFielToNull = true;
            for (Field f : fieldObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
              f.setAccessible(true);
              if(f.get(fieldObj) != null) {
                setFielToNull = false;
                break;
              }
            }
            if(setFielToNull) {
              setFieldToNull(obj, field);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while setting empty string or object to null: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

  private void setFieldToNull(Object obj, Field field) throws IllegalAccessException {
    if(!Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) {
      field.set(obj, null);
    }
  }

  private boolean isPrimitiveOrWrapper(Class fieldType)  {
    return fieldType.isPrimitive()
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Byte.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Character.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Float.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Long.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Double.class)
        || fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Short.class);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different DTO for cached object.

For example, you can create `UserCached` class and keep there only fields you need.
After that, create mapper to map objects back & forth. `Mapstruct` is good for that.

Such approach solves the problem, decouples your application, and makes changes in your primary DTO more safe to make.