# java gson replace password value while serialization

Tags: java, customization, deserialization, gson

How can I replace the value of a password field with `XXX` while de-serializing an object with Gson? I found this post: [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations) that basically skips the field. This would be an option, but I still would prefer to replace the value with `XXX`

I also tried this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new JsonSerializer<String>(){

  @Override public JsonElement serialize(String value, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2){
        // could not find a way to determine the field name     
        return new JsonPrimitive(value);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to determine the name of the field. So is there any other option?

I use Gson to log some objects the "pretty" way, so I don't need to bother with the formatting while reading the logs.

Comment: you want to mask the password while converting Java object to JSON; or the vice-versa?

Comment: It is more likely that he wants to hide the passwords when serializing ... because that's when they would be likely to "leak".

Comment: Hey @Nishant, yes, I would like to mask the password for the direction java => json (string) being able to log the information. Thank you. Kon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel pretty lame while posting this answer. But, it's what you can, it essentially copies and changes the Java object, before serializing.

```
public class User {
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    public String name;
    public String password;

    public User(String name, String pwd){
        this.name = name;
        this.password = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return new User(this.name, this.password);
    }

    public static void main(String[] aa){
        JsonSerializer<User> ser = new JsonSerializer<User>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(User u, Type t, JsonSerializationContext ctx) {
                try {
                    User clone = (User)u.clone();
                    clone.password = clone.password.replaceAll(".","x");
                    return (gson.toJsonTree(clone, User.class));
                } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                    //do something if you dont liek clone.
                }
                return gson.toJsonTree(u, User.class);
            }
        };
        Gson g = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(User.class, ser).create();
        System.out.println(g.toJson(new User("naishe", "S3cr37")));
    }
}
```

Gets serialized to:

```
{"name":"naishe","password":"xxxxxx"}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the cloning step, just serialize it normally and then replace the password:

```
public JsonElement serialize(User u, Type t, JsonSerializationContext ctx) {
          JsonObject obj = new Gson().toJsonTree(u).getAsJsonObject();
          obj.remove("password");
          obj.add("password", new JsonPrimitive("xxxxx");
          return obj;
}
```