# Read custom ArrayList in SharedPreferences invoke runtime exception

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, classloader, runtimeexception

I'm making an application like Nike running app. TrackerService class is a Service which saves workout record on stop() and then reloads data from sharedPreferences on `resume()`. After I searched several solutions, I implemented the way that parses ArrayList to Json. On first try stop() to resume(), workout records restored successfully but when it comes to second try stop() to resume(), RunTimeException has occurred.

How can I solve this problem?

```
  package smu.ac.kr.johnber.run;

  import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
  import android.app.Service;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.SharedPreferences;
  import android.location.Location;
  import android.os.Binder;
  import android.os.IBinder;
  import android.os.Looper;
  import android.os.SystemClock;

  import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
  import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
  import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
  import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
  import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
  import com.google.gson.Gson;
  import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
  import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.HashSet;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Set;

  import smu.ac.kr.johnber.util.RecordUtil;

  import static smu.ac.kr.johnber.util.LogUtils.LOGD;
  import static smu.ac.kr.johnber.util.LogUtils.makeLogTag;

  /**
   * RunningFragment 와 통신
   *  - data의 전송은 callback listener을 사용
   * 달리기 기록 측정을 위한 Service
   * requestLocationUpdates()할 때 마다 거리, 칼로리를 계산한다.
   */
  public class TrackerService extends Service {

      private final String TAG = "TrackerService.class";
      private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 101;
      private static final String PERMISSION = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

      // status flag
      private static final int INIT = 20000;
      private static final int START = 20001;
      private static final int PAUSE = 20002;
      private static final int RESUME = 20003;
      private static final int STOP = 20003;

      private final IBinder mIBinder = new TrackerBinder();
      private TrackerCallback mtrackerCallback;
      private Record mRecord;
      private int mState;
      private double distance;
      private double elapsedTime;
      private double calories;
  //    private ArrayList<LatLng> location;
      private Location mCurrentLocation;
      private Location mLastLocation;
      private Location mActivityLastLocation; // 처음 start할때 location
      private ArrayList<Location> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<Location>();
      private Date date;
      private double startTime;
      private double currentTime;
      private String title;
      private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
      private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
  //    private Location mCurrentLocation;
      private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
  //TODO : user 객체를 앱 로그인 성공후 사용자 만들어 놓고 weight만 getter로 받아와서 사용할 수 있도록 하기
      private double weight = 70.0;

      public TrackerService() {
      }

      /**
       * 서비스에서 제공하는 public 함수들을 사용하기 위한 통신채널
       *
       */
      public class TrackerBinder extends Binder {
          //외부에서 함수 호출시 RecService의 레퍼런스를 돌려줄 수 있도록함
          public TrackerService getService(){
              return TrackerService.this;
          }
      }


      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          LOGD(TAG,"onCreate");
          // location 받아오기위한 준비
          mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
          mLocationRequest = getLocationRequest();
          createLocationCallback();

      }

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          LOGD(TAG, "onStartCommand");
          return START_STICKY;
      }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          LOGD(TAG,"onBind");
          // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.

         return mIBinder;
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          LOGD(TAG, "onDestroy");
          mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
      }

      /**
       * 운동기록 변화에 따라 RunningActivity UI반영을 위한 콜백 메소드
       */
      public interface TrackerCallback {
          public void onDistanceChanged(double value);
          public void onCaloriesChanged(double value);
          public void onElapsedtimeChanged(double value);
          public void onLocationChanged(LatLng from, LatLng value);
  //TODO:
          public void onPausedLisenter(Record record);
      }

  //    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
  //    private void startLocationTracking() {
  //        LOGD(TAG, "enableLocationTracking : check permission");
  //                //TODO : request current location
  //                LOGD(TAG, "Start location tracking");
  //                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
  //    }
      /**
       * LocationRequest 설정
       - interval
       - fastest interval
       - priority
       */
      private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
          @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
          LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
          locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
          //5 seconds
          locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
          locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
          return locationRequest;
      }

      /**
       mFusedLocationClient로 부터 위치를 받았을 때 실행할 콜백 메소드
       매 위치가 바뀔때마다 기록 측정
       */
      private void createLocationCallback() {
          mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                  super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                  // INIT -> START하는경우 LastLocation 설정
                  if (mState == INIT) {
                      //RUN버튼 누른 시점의 위치
                      mActivityLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                      //ArrayList에 시작 location 저장
                      mLastLocation = mActivityLastLocation;

                      locationArrayList.add(mLastLocation);

                  }
                  startImpl(locationResult);
              }
          };
      }

      // 변수들 초기화
      public void init(){
          mState = INIT;
          distance = 0;
          elapsedTime = 0;
          calories = 0;
  //        location = null;
          mCurrentLocation = null;
          mLastLocation = null;
          mActivityLastLocation = null;
          if (locationArrayList != null) {
              if (!locationArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                  locationArrayList.clear();
                  LOGD(TAG,"locationList cleared"+locationArrayList.size());
              }
          }
          currentTime = 0;
          startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
          date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
      /**
       * state 확인 ( resume인경우 이전값에 이어서 측정)
       *  locationrequestUpdates (onLocationResult콜백이 호출되고, 여기서 운동기록 측정 함수 호출)
       *  Timer.start
       */
      @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
      public void start(int Action) {

          LOGD(TAG, "start tracking");
          // set state
          switch (Action) {
              case INIT:
                  mState = INIT;
                  break;
              case RESUME:
                  mState = RESUME;
                  break;
          }

          if(mState != RESUME){
              //init variables
              init();
          } else if (mState == RESUME) {
              //reload variables from sharedPreferences
              resume();
          }
          mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
          //기록 계산은 requsetLocationUpdates()에 따른 콜백 메소드인 onLocationResult에서 이루어짐 -> startImpl()
          //변수 초기화

      }

      // TODO : 운동기록 측정 함수  , mCallback의 각 함수 호출
      public void startImpl(LocationResult locationResult){
          mState = START;

          //거리 측정
          mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
          //ArrayList에 location 저장
          locationArrayList.add(mCurrentLocation);
          LOGD(TAG,"size of location list"+locationArrayList.size());
          LatLng from = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
          LatLng to = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
          if(!from.equals(to))
              //mLastLocation~mCurrentLocation간 거리 구하기
            distance +=  SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from,to);
          LOGD(TAG, "기록 측정"+"Current: "+from.toString()+"  Last: "+to.toString()+" distance: "+Integer.toString((int)distance));
          //runningfragment에서 오버라이딩한 onDistanceChanged를 호출하여 UI업데이트
          mtrackerCallback.onDistanceChanged(distance);
          mtrackerCallback.onLocationChanged(from,to);
          //운동시간
          elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
          //평균속도
          double averageSpeed = distance / elapsedTime;
          LOGD(TAG, "sppeed: " + averageSpeed+" dist and elapsed "+distance+"  "+elapsedTime);
          //칼로리 계산
          calories = RecordUtil.getAverageCalories(weight, elapsedTime);
          LOGD(TAG,"calories:"+calories);
          mtrackerCallback.onCaloriesChanged(calories);
          //LastLocation 업데이트
          mLastLocation = mCurrentLocation;
      }


      /**
       * sharedPreference로 부터 데이터 복원
       * - distance
       * - calories
       * - elapsedTime
       * - startTime
       * - locationArrayList
       * - lastLocation
       *      locationArrayList.get(마지막)값으로 복원
       */
      public void resume() {
          SharedPreferences preferences;
          preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("savedRecord", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

          Gson gson = new Gson();
          String response = preferences.getString("LOCATIONLIST", "");

          locationArrayList = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Location>>() {}.getType());
              LOGD(TAG, "size of saved array list " + locationArrayList.size());
              mLastLocation = locationArrayList.get(locationArrayList.size() - 1);
             LOGD(TAG, "lat of last location" + mLastLocation.getLatitude());

          // 나머지 복원
          distance = Double.parseDouble(preferences.getString("DISTANCE", ""));
          elapsedTime = Double.parseDouble(preferences.getString("ELAPSEDTIME", ""));
          calories = Double.parseDouble(preferences.getString("CALORIES", ""));
          startTime = Double.parseDouble(preferences.getString("STARTTIME", ""));
          LOGD(TAG, "distance: " + distance + " elapsedTime: " + elapsedTime + " statTime: " + startTime);
          mState = RESUME;
      }

      /**
       * save 기록
       * 자원 해제
       * stopSelf()
       */
      public void stop() {
          double endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
  //        mRecord = new Record(distance,elapsedTime,calories, locationArrayList,date, startTime, endTime, date.toString());
          /**
           * sharedPreference에 Record값 저장
           */
          //TODO:
          //locaitonArrayList저장
          SharedPreferences preferences;
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
          preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("savedRecord", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

          Gson gson = new Gson();
          String json = gson.toJson(locationArrayList);
          editor = preferences.edit();
          editor.putString("LOCATIONLIST", json);
          editor.apply();


          // 나머지 저장
          //TODO : String으로 변환해 저장 한 후 데이터 복원시 double로 다시 복원
          editor.putString("DISTANCE", Double.toString(distance));
          editor.putString("ELAPSEDTIME", Double.toString(elapsedTime));
          editor.putString("CALORIES", Double.toString(calories));
          //TODO : Date와 Title은 firebase에 Record 객체를 저장하기 전에 설정할것
          editor.putString("STARTTIME", Double.toString(startTime));
          editor.putString("ENDTIME", Double.toString(endTime));
          editor.commit();

          //서비스 종료
          this.stopSelf();
          LOGD(TAG, "stopTrackerService");
      }

      /**
       * RunningFragment에 데이터 전달을 위한 callback listener를 등록/해제
       */
      public void registerCallback(TrackerCallback callback){
          mtrackerCallback = callback;
      }

      public void unregisterCallback(TrackerCallback callback){
          mtrackerCallback = null;
      }

  }
```

05-14 01:43:03.974 1276-1276/smu.ac.kr.johnber E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    Process: smu.ac.kr.johnber, PID: 1276
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.lang.ClassLoader() with no args
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:111)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
        at smu.ac.kr.johnber.run.TrackerService.resume(TrackerService.java:284)
        at smu.ac.kr.johnber.run.TrackerService.start(TrackerService.java:227)
        at smu.ac.kr.johnber.run.RunningFragment$1.onServiceConnected(RunningFragment.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1453)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1481)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class java.lang.ClassLoader
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:108)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
        at smu.ac.kr.johnber.run.TrackerService.resume(TrackerService.java:284) 
        at smu.ac.kr.johnber.run.TrackerService.start(TrackerService.java:227) 
        at smu.ac.kr.johnber.run.RunningFragment$1.onServiceConnected(RunningFragment.java:226) 
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1453) 
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1481) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944346/runtimeexception-in-gson-parsing-json-failed-to-invoke-protected-java-lang-clas.

Comment: please make an answer instead adding the answer to your question.

Comment: I added answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Instead create Gson object with its constructor, I made GsonBuilder and attach serializeNulls() It worked successfully

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.serializeNulls();
```