# Ignore Null Value Fields From Rest API Response Java

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

In my project when i send Rest Response to **Advance Rest Client** It only shows Fields which Have some values and Ignores(Does not show) fields which have NULL Values or Empty values.

Part Of Code:

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
// firstResponse is Object which contains the values
String jsonString = gson.toJson(firstResponse);
test.saveJson(jsonString); //OR System.out.println(jsonString);            
return Response.ok(firstResponse).build(); // Response to Rest Client
```

Response sample To `return Response.ok(firstResponse).build();`

Advance rest client From web project :

```
{
  "Name": "smith",
  "Properties": {
    "propertyList": [
      {
        "ID": "072",
        "Number": "415151",
        "Address": "Somewhere"
      },
      {
        "ID": "151",
        "Number": "a800cc79-99d1-42f1-aeb4-808087b12c9b",
        "Address": "ninink"
      },
      {
        "ID": "269",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Now when i save this as Json String in DB or When i want to Print this to console it also prints the fiels with null  or empty values:

```
{
  "Name": "smith",
  "Properties": {
    "propertyList": [
      {
        "ID": "072",
        "Number": "415151",
        "Address": "Somewhere"
      },
      {
        "ID": "151",
        "Number": "a800cc79-99d1-42f1-aeb4-808087b12c9b",
        "Address": "ninink"
      },
      {
        "ID": "269",
        "Number": "",
        "Address": ""
      },

    ],
  },
  "resultList" :[]
}
```

How can i print or save this JSON string same as response in rest client i.e. i dont want to print null or empty value field i just want to ignore them.

Comment: I suspect it is the translation of this JSON string to your Java object that is adding these values just before saving in database.

Comment: how to resolve this ??

Comment: First verify by querying the DB directly whether this is indeed the case. If that is true then post your domain class for this JSON as well.

Comment: i just want to print values without null fields

Answer (score 2):

in top og entity class , try with the annotation

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

this annotation don't show any empty field in your json.

Answer (score 1):

Not giving you a code but here are some pointers for you:

- Read the manual: [**`How to handle NULL values`**](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support)
- You may need to use a [**`custom exclusion strategy`**](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html)
- Also read this Q&A: [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)

Comment: 1st doesnt ignore null fields rather it shows null values i have a long response with lots of lists in there cant we have Response.ok(firstResponse).build() in db or console to simply ignore null fields or cant we convert this Response to json i tried with get entity but result was same

Comment: As I wrote: `You may need to use a custom exclusion strategy` and for example on that use linked Q&A.