# Gson stackoverflow Gson.fromJson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, stack-overflow

I am executing a Web Service, and this is my response, bu when I try convert this JSONObject(org.json.JSONObject) to specific object using Gson library, my app crashes.
So, I don't know why happened this.
JSON:

```
{
"atributos": {
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "Cliente",
    "descripcion": "Cliente",
    "version": "1"
},
"elementos": "[{
    "id": "1",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "6",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "7",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "9",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "10",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "11",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "12",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "13",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "14",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "15",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "16",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "17",
    "name" : "akira"
},
{
    "id": "18",
    "name" : "akira"
}]"
}
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
05-02 17:50:56.166: E/AndroidRuntime(8130):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
```

Comment: Show your Java code, and try to be clear in describing what you're trying to do, and what is the problem.

Comment: What is your question, where is your code?

Comment: The JSON seems like it's a complete mess. Doesn't seem valid at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i validate ur given json it have some error  (The Example Json give is not a valid json).Your json have  **"** in elementos array before opening and close ,maybe that causing a stack overflow error when you try to parse the json using Gson.

> "elementos": "[{.....]"

Please verfy you json with some json validator site for Example [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

So first we need to valid json ,i have made ur json vaild by omitting the **"**

it will be like this

Your Json after the change

```
{
"atributos": {
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "Cliente",
    "descripcion": "Cliente",
    "version": "1"
},
"elementos": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "akira"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "name": "akira"
    }
]
}
```

**Now the Coding Part : ** To parse this jsonresponse using Gson please follow the Steps below

**Make a class JsonResponse**

```
public class JsonResponse {

 /*Class handle the Whole json*/

//Variable name should be same as the names given in the json response  

Atributos atributos;// Attributos class handles the data in atributos obj from the json . The variable name of Attributos should be same as the json objects ie atributos

ArrayList<ElementosObj>elementos=null;//elementos is a array which hold some datas  ,so make a class ElementosObj to handle the data in the  elementos array.


}
```

**Class Atributos**

```
public class Atributos {

 /*Class handle the atributos obj from json*/

  //Variable name should be same as the names given in the json response
public String id = null;
public String nombre = null;
public String descripcion = null;
public String version = null;
}
```

**Class ElementosObj**

```
public class ElementosObj {

/*Class handle the elementos array from json*/

//Variable name should be same as the names given in the json response

String id=null;
String name=null;

}
```

*And now in your main class where you Parse The Above json*

**Main class**

```
String jsonData = "String jsonData Contain your parsed jsondata ";


    Gson mGson = new Gson();
    JsonResponse mObj1 = (JsonResponse) mGson.fromJson(jsonData,
            JsonResponse.class);

    Log.d("Atributos:ID", mObj1.atributos.id);
    Log.d("Atributos:DESCRIBTION", mObj1.atributos.descripcion);
    Log.d("Atributos:NUMBER", mObj1.atributos.nombre);
    Log.d("Atributos:VERSION", mObj1.atributos.version);

    for (int i = 0; i < mObj1.elementos.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("Elementos:ID For Postion " + i, mObj1.elementos.get(i).id);
        Log.d("Elementos:NAME For Postion " + i,
                mObj1.elementos.get(i).name);
    }
```

The Output will be like this

```
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Atributos:ID: 1
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Atributos:DESCRIBTION: Cliente
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Atributos:NUMBER: Cliente
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Atributos:VERSION: 1
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 0: 1
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 0: akira
05-03 01:32:51.548: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 1: 4
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 1: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 2: 5
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 2: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 3: 6
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 3: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 4: 7
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 4: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 5: 8
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 5: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 6: 9
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 6: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 7: 10
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 7: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 8: 11
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 8: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 9: 12
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 9: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 10: 13
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 10: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 11: 14
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 11: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 12: 15
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 12: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 13: 16
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 13: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 14: 17
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 14: akira
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:ID For Postion 15: 18
05-03 01:32:51.558: D/Elementos:NAME For Postion 15: akira
```

Hope this will help you
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this, the problem in my case was that I needed to replace:

```
private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

with

```
private transient Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

Note the keyword "transient".  This is further explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889590/2308858.