# Parsing only a part from a large JSON

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

[image]I have a URL which contains contains a JSON array of some objects that I need for my android application.I've written the mapping class for these objects and also added

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

for some fields that are unimportant for my end.My problem is that other than my precious data this URL also contains some extra and unnecessary information that I do not need to parse nor create a mapping class for in my part. I'm also using Jackson for quick parsing the JSON. So my question: how can I parse the whole URL but map only the desired JSON Array?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,post[]> map = mapper.readValue(new URL(urls.get(0)), Map.class);
System.out.println(map.get("posts").length);
```

what I've written above compiles just fine but when I try to get the array of posts I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList`

here's my code

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Trial obj = mapper.readValue(new URL(urls.get(0)), Trial.class);
            System.out.println(obj.pois.size());



        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





        return "done";
    }
```

**Trial class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 public class Trial {

public String status;
public String count;
public String pages;
public ArrayList<PointOfInterest> pois;
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public String getPages() {
    return pages;
}
public void setPages(String pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}
public ArrayList<PointOfInterest> getPois() {
    return pois;
}
public void setPois(ArrayList<PointOfInterest> pois) {
    this.pois = pois;
}

}
```

**Post Class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Post{

public String title;
public String content;
public String id;
public String categoryIdFirstLevel;
public String categoryIdSecondLevel;
public String categoryIdThirdLevel;
public String categoryIdFourthLevel;
public String latitude;
public String longitude;


public Post(){

}

public Post(String title,String content,String id,String first,String second,String third,String fourth,String lat,String lon,ArrayList<String> urls){

    this.title=title;
    this.content=content;
    this.id=id;
    this.categoryIdFirstLevel=first;
    this.categoryIdSecondLevel=second;
    this.categoryIdThirdLevel=third;
    this.categoryIdFourthLevel=fourth;
    this.latitude=lat;
    this.longitude=lon;


}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCategoryIdFirstLevel() {
    return categoryIdFirstLevel;
}

public void setCategoryIdFirstLevel(String categoryIdFirstLevel) {
    this.categoryIdFirstLevel = categoryIdFirstLevel;
}

public String getCategoryIdSecondLevel() {
    return categoryIdSecondLevel;
}

public void setCategoryIdSecondLevel(String categoryIdSecondLevel) {
    this.categoryIdSecondLevel = categoryIdSecondLevel;
}

public String getCategoryIdThirdLevel() {
    return categoryIdThirdLevel;
}

public void setCategoryIdThirdLevel(String categoryIdThirdLevel) {
    this.categoryIdThirdLevel = categoryIdThirdLevel;
}

public String getCategoryIdFourthLevel() {
    return categoryIdFourthLevel;
}

public void setCategoryIdFourthLevel(String categoryIdFourthLevel) {
    this.categoryIdFourthLevel = categoryIdFourthLevel;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}


}
```

Comment: do you have access to the webservice code ? Why sending data you don't need ?

Comment: Please post the code causing the exception!

Comment: well that's another story..I know you are right but I do not have access to the webservice

Comment: can you show the JSON and tell us which part you dont want to map?

Comment: well the file is a bit large and it won't make sense, I'll post a photo after it's been formated with online JSON viewer

Comment: I can barely see anything

Comment: GSON (as example I know) has 2 ways of parsing JSON. Either "document model" or "streaming". You need to look to see if Jackson allows this streaming method.

Comment: @SMR sorry, can you zoom in? what streaming has to do with it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jackson but with GSON is farly easy just see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parse it like this because there are other properties also in JSON:

```
Map<String, post[]> map = mapper.readValue(new URL(urls.get(0)), Map.class);
```

What you should do is create a class that contains the posts array:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
static class Post {
    public int id;
    public String type;
}
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Mapper {
    public ArrayList<Post> posts;
}
```

and then parse the JSON:

```
Mapper obj = mapper.readValue(json, Mapper.class);
```

Edit1: added JsonIgnoreProperties annotation to Post too

Comment: this didn't work either..I'll post you my classes just to see if I'm missing something

Comment: in the 'Trial' class you use a 'PointOfInterest' class but you posted the 'Post' class

Comment: that's not it...I actually use that name for my class, I just wrote post in my question here in stackoverflow. for reasons of simplicity

Comment: Do you still get the ClassCastException?