# how to Have different ExclusionStrategy for request and response in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I've implemented [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803346/3248593) but i want different strategies for excluding my fields in "request" and "response". how can i do that?

**Update:** for example, i want to send name and last name in request and exclude the others but in response i want email to be included.

Model:

```
public class User{
@Expose
@SerializedName("id")
private String mRemoteId;

@Expose
@Column(name = "name")
@SerializedName("name")
private String mName;

@Expose
@Column(name = "lastName")
@SerializedName("lastname")
private String mLastName;

@Expose
@Column(name = "email")
@SerializedName("email")
private String mEmail;

@Expose
@Column(name = "password")
@SerializedName("password")
private String mPassword;
}
```