# Remove __hashCodeCalc from JSON String

Tags: java, json

I am new to JSON and trying to convert an object to JSON , it is adding an 
`"__hashCodeCalc":false` to it. I don't know what that means. how can I remove it before sending this JSON object ?

```
System.out.println("Person JSON element " + new Gson().toJson(person));
```

Comment: You may find the answers here useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations