# How to exclude a Java Object Property as part of JSON String?

Tags: java, json

I have a Java POJO. Few properties are there along with a list<>. While converting this object to JSON String, I want to exclude the list property,
So what annotation to use for that?

```
public class StudentResultSummary {
    private String totMarks;
    private String avgMarks;
    private List<StudentResult> resultList = new ArrayList<StudentResult>();
}
```

Convert to JSON:

```
StudentResultSummary resultSummary = new StudentResultSummary();
Json json = new Json();
policySummary = json.encode(resultSummary);
```

How can I make sure the field resultList is not included as part of the JSON response?

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: import io.vertx.core.json.Json;

Answer (score 4):

From [Chris Seline's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889590/2823516):

> Any fields you don't want serialized in general you should use the
>   "transient" modifier, and this also applies to json serializers (at
>   least it does to a few that I have used, including gson).
>
> If you don't want name to show up in the serialized json give it a
>   **transient keyword**, eg:
>
> ```
> private transient String name;
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If You don't want to that column in response json you can use @JsonIgnore 
and if you don't want to that field in table you should use @Transient

```
 @Transient
    private String password_key_type; 

    @JsonIgnore
    public int getUser_id()
    {
    return user_id;
    }
```