# GSON - How to only return a list of a certain subobject?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using an api to get data for my application. I parse the JSON data using GSON so I have something looing like this:

```
List
    obj
        double
        movie
            ...
    obj
        double
        movie
            ...
    ...
```

The double value is used for weighting the order of the movies. However, I am not intrested in that, and would instead look a plain list of movies, like this:

```
List
    movie
        ...
    movie
        ...
    ...
```

The only solution I can think of is first parsing it to a list of obj and then using a loop to copy the movie objects to a new list, but I was hoping you could teach me a better method. What are your suggestions?

Comment: May be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) library, along with `JSONExpression` to extract the required element(s) from `JSON`. E.g. in case of below json:

```
[{
    "test": 1,
    "test1": "value1"
},
{
    "test": 1,
    "test1": "value2"
}]
```

If you want to get all the values of `test1` element then, you can use `$[*].test1` `JSONExpression` to get both `value1` and `value2`. See the java example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object value = JsonPath.read("[{    \"test\": 1,    \"test1\": \"value1\"},{    \"test\": 1,    \"test1\": \"value2\"}]", "$[*].test1");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

[This](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) is a good website to test `JSON` expressions on the fly.

***edit***
Maven dependency for JsonPath :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I seem to get an error when adding it to my dependencies. Is `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0` the correct one?

Comment: Updated the answer with dependency :)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that giving your field the transient keyword should do the trick:

```
private transient double value;
```

This should exclude it from serialization.