# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.text.DecimalFormat declares multiple JSON fields named maximumIntegerDigits

Tags: java, gson, illegalargumentexception, decimalformat

I am making an ajax call to the servlet. I want the data back from the servlet to the jsp:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String isbn = (String) request.getParameter("isbn");
    BookDetail bd = new BookDetail();
    if(bd.ISBNFound(isbn)){
    ArrayList<KitapData> Books = bd.LoadBooksByISBN(isbn);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(Books);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    System.out.print(json);      
    out.print(json);
}
```

I've added the GSon.jar in the classpath. But Iam getting some error: Complete list is as follows: What am i missing here?

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Book_CheckISBN]: Servlet.service() for servlet Book_CheckISBN threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.text.DecimalFormat declares multiple JSON fields named maximumIntegerDigits
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
    at book.ctrl.Book_CheckISBN.doPost(Book_CheckISBN.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Where is the `JSon` ?

Comment: Should I add any other library for JSON ?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your `Json`

Comment: Can you give me an example, that fetches data from database, stores in an arraylist and then converts to JSON.

Comment: i think this is a case if you have a member in class `Book` or other sub class of type `DecimalFormat` ex, `private final java.text.DecimalFormat...`, check this https://github.com/google/gson/issues/399 find the reply by user **wxi**

Answer (score 12):

My case is a `SimpleDateFormat` field in the DO causing the error, 
 after adding
`transient` to it,  problem solved

Comment: @JavierHeisecke, its a keyword to skip certain variable during serialization, in my case its just no need to save a SimpleDateFormat  field in the DO and pass it around, so we can skip it by adding transient.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that you actually want to be serializing a field of type `DecimalFormat` to JSON. If you can modify the `KitapData` class, you can consider removing the field, or making it `transient` which will tell Gson (and other serializers) to ignore the field.

```
private transient DecimalFormat whateverTheFieldIsCalled;
```

If you can't modify the `KitapData` class there are other ways to tell Gson to exclude the field from serialization - for example see [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Your class `KitapData` has somewhere a `DecimalFormat` property. Gson is falling over it because it's not a standard Java type for which it has builtin support such as `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, `List`, etc.

You need to remove that `DecimalFormat` property. Not only because Gson can't digest it automatically without having [registered a type adapter](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization), but also because it can impossibly represent a "bean property" and it's essentially tight-coupling. Moreover, `NumberFormat` is like `DateFormat` all friends **not threadsafe**. Having it as a bean property suggests that it's shareable among multiple threads. This may result in corrupt formatting or even exceptions.

Perhaps you only wanted to store a the format pattern or other related properties. In that case, store them as `String`, `Integer`, etc instead and make sure the code always creates a brand new `DecimalFormat` instance in the method local scope based on those "loose" properties.