# How to deserialize a JSON HashMap<String, Object>?

Tags: java, json, spring

This is my situation:

```
private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

public void setName(String x) {put("name", x);}
public String getName() {return (String)get("name");}

public void setAge(Integer x) {put("age", x);}
public Integer getAge() {return (Integer)get("age");}

public void setUUID(UUID x) {put("uuid", x);}
public UUID getUUID() {return (UUID)get("uuid");}
```

Now when I generate JSON from this object I get {"data":{"name": ...}}
I don't want the "data":{} part.

How to fix this?

[EDIT] When this class is exported as JSON by Spring the format is exactly what I want.

Comment: how are you generating the JSON object? Normally there is no data part.

Comment: new Gson().toJson(myClass);

Comment: does the data belong to the "Person" class??

Comment: There are a few solutions [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations). You can mark it as transient, or you can expose the ones you wish and then grab them only via your Gson API.

Comment: @Expose has no effect. When I use transient my JSON is empty {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your entire class seems to be inside a map, simply add a getter method for the Map to you class and instead of serializing the class itself, do it like:

```
gson.toJson(foo.getData())
```

On a side note, I gotta say it is pretty awkward having getters and setters doing actions on a map.