# Gson avoid reflection

Tags: java, reflection, gson

Is there a way to avoid reflection in Gson? I know that when you will use `registerTypeAdapter` you can avoid it, but if you use `@SerializedName("name")` annotation on class member, can you avoid id too?

Comment: Everything serializers do involves reflection. To use the `TypeAdapter` Gson has to determine the type of your object.  Can you clarify why you need this, what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: And aren't runtime annotations determined using reflection?

Comment: I think Soltirios wants a way to exclude  a field inspection through reflexion (performance or to avoid infinite cycles). If that's the case check documentation or this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Reflection is very slow on android, this is why I want to avoid it ;). I saw an article, where authors wrote, that using TypeAdapter and custom deserializers we can avoid reflection. But I'm just curious that there is another way to achieve that

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider it depends on annotation implementation. Some of anntotations use reflection, but some of them use code injection.

Comment: Yes reflection is slow, but you should be doing this work on a background thread so it typically not that big of a deal.

Comment: @cyroxis there is no way to do it on main thread, because I'm doing network calls. On android reflection is a lot slower than on pure java, there are a lot of articles about that. My question was simple - Do `@SerializedName` uses reflection or not?

Comment: Yes it uses reflection. Yes reflection is slower on Android. I am using Gson in an Android project and deserializing 10k+ entities from single network calls. It is typically not a big issues if you don't block the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Autovalue](https://github.com/google/auto) and [Autovalue-gson](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson) that will create a reflection free adapter for you.