# Gson remove unnecessary nested object fields

Tags: android, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am trying to serialize an object. I have the following structure:

```
Class A{
String aField1;
String aField2;
B bObj;
}
Class B{
String bField1;
String bField2;
String bField3;    
}
```

I am trying to serialze class A and B objects to send them to server.
When I am serializing *Class A* object, it gives me

```
{
 aField1: "abc",
 aField2: "def",
 B: {
    bField1: "mnp",
    bField2: "qrt",
    bField3: "xyz",
    }
}
```

And serializing *Class B* obj:

```
{
 bField1: "mnp",
 bField2: "qrt",
 bField3: "xyz",
}
```

But I want *Class A* object like this:

```
{
 aField1: "abc",
 aField2: "def",
 B: {
    bField1: "mnp"
    }
}
```

I am currently using **GSON** library to accomplish this.
I want to remove extra key value pairs when interacting with server. **How can I do this?**

Comment: Use the `@Expose` annotation https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Gson-s-Expose to choose exactly which fields are serialised

Comment: I need all those field in while serializing Class B obj.

Comment: Using exclusion strategy is the solution to this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4803346/2920114

Answer (score 0):

Change your Serialize class like this way.

```
public class A implements Serializable{
    String aField1;
    String aField2;
    B bObj;

    class B{
        String bField1;
        String bField2;
        String bField3;
    }
}
```

Just remove the extra fields. It will not make any problem.

Comment: I need those fields.

Comment: I want to make json object for Class A and for Class B also. while making json object for class B, I need all the fields but while making json for Class A, I need some specific field of Class B to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark `bField2` and `bField3` as `transient` or use the annotation `@Expose(serialize = false)`.

Or you can customize your serialization exclusion strategy.
Sample code:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Type type = new TypeToken <A>(){}.getType();
builder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(
        new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
                return fieldAttributes.getName().equals("bField2") ||
                            fieldAttributes.getName().equals("bField3");
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                return false;
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: `Type type = new TypeToken <A>(){}.getType();` is not required and  this: equals("bField3") --> `)` <--; a syntax error - by fixing that the code block works

Comment: No problem :), what about the second line `Type`, is there any reason to keep it ?

Comment: @emecas, actually, `builder.create().fromJson(reader, type)` will return the deserialized object