# Gson: Excluding field on specific class using without annotations - 2

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Currently i working on serialising an java object to JSON using Gson.
I am trying to skip a field in a class but not on the other class.

Sample code:

```
Class A {
 var a;
 var b;
}

Class B {
 var a;
 var c;
}

Class C {
 class A;
 class B;
}
```

I want to exclude **a** only on **A**, but not on **B**. I can't place annotations on the fields as the object is not owned by me or access object **A** and remove **a** manually. I am looking for some generic approach.

Similar question : [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)
which answer provided by Nishant matches the thought of mine. But I feel that the solution is not fully correct as the below condition provided there is wrong.

> f.getDeclaringClass() == c

GetDeclaringClass is returning the type of the class not the parent class.

I wrote similar custom exclusion strategies using Gson. With exclusion strategy, I can do the following

> shouldSkipClass(class)
>
> shouldSkipField(fieldAttributes).

But I am expecting the combination of both skip if this fieldAttributes is present only in the provided class.

> shouldSkipFieldUnderClass(class, fieldAttributes)

Are there any other ways to achieve the same? or am i doing anything wrong above? Please provide me suggestions to skip fields in specific class using Gson.

Comment: Apologies, found my issue. I have been using getDeclaredClass instead of getDeclaringClass. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to exclude a only on A, but not on B.

Then declare the field **a** as [transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3)

```
Class A {
 var transient a;
 var b;
}

Class B {
 var a;
 var c;
}

Class C {
 class A;
 class B;
}
```

Comment: The model is coming from external service, so i can't modify it.