# In JSON serialization howto ignore some of Class1 field(s) in case Class1 is a field of Class2?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I searched for this question on stackoverflow and google and I couldn't find any proper answer.

How do I ignore fields from an object within an object?

I think it will be much easier to understand with an example:

(Editors note, in title: `Class1`=`Engine` a field for `Class2`=`Car`)

```
class Car {
    Integer id;
    Integer numberOfWheels;
    Engine engine;
}   

class Engine {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String producer;
    Integer horsePower;
    Integer weight; 
}
```

The Car JSON should consist of all fields, but the Engine object within the Car object should be limited to `id, name, producer`.

```
{
  "id":1,
  "numberOfWheels":4,
  "engine": {
    "id":1,
    "name":"some engine"
    "producer":"some engine producer"
  }
}
```

The Engine JSON should however consist of all fields `id, name, producer, horsePower, weight`

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"some engine"
    "producer":"some engine producer"
    "horsePower":250
    "weight":500
}
```

Just to clarify. The fields `horsePower` and `weight` should only be ignored in the JSON generated from Car.

Comment: Can you use gson or do you need to rely on Spring json libs? Unfamiliar to Spring and its json handling, what json implementation Spring uses?

Comment: I can use gson, I do not have to stick to spring only. I am just looking for the best practice and typesafe solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on `gson`s `JsonSerializer` and `ExclusionStrategy`. Maybe not the most terse way to do it - especially compared to your own solution - but a good option in general.

To enable `Car` to have some special treatment create `JsonSerializer` like

```
public class CarSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Car> {
    private final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new FieldExclusionStrategy()).create();

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Car arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
        return new JsonParser().parse(gson.toJson(arg0));
    }
}
```

Above has its own `gson` to handle only `Car` and not to mess any other serialization. Beforementioned registers `ExclusionStrategy` to its own private use that checks that if `Car`s field is `Engine` then any unwanted field in `Engine` is skipped.

```
public class FieldExclusionStrategy  implements ExclusionStrategy {
    private Set<String> ignored = 
            new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList( new String[]{"horsePower","weight"}));
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes arg0) {
        if(arg0.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(Engine.class))
            if(ignored.contains(arg0.getName())) return true;
        return false;
    }       
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) { return false; }
}
```

And it can be used with `gson` that registers `JsonSerializer` as its type adapter for `Car.class`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
      .registerTypeAdapter(Car.class, new CarSerializer()).create();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. The only issue with the solution is that it is not typesafe given that you have to provided the exclusions as Strings. I do however struggle too see how this can be done typesafe and I guess there is not perfect solution for this. I am unsure if it is wroth the effort to create ExclusionStrategy, because this could potential be a lot of exclusions for the same object but for different wrapper objects. Would you recommend to use ExclusionStrategy over my solution? This is not for a specific problem, I just want to find the best practice solution

Comment: Yes, not typesafe all the way and not perfect in error checking either. But i guess you can handle that part from this point on i'm sure it is possible still. What comes to your solution it is good once in a lifetime but i tend to prefer stuff that does not interfere with entities/models in other words my solution is kind a view to your entities/models and you can create as many views you want without  modifying your classes anymore or possibly pose them to some nasty side-effects.

Comment: Very good point about cross cutting concerns. Thanks a lot for your help. It is always great with a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I got impatience and decided to create a temporary solution until I find a better way. This solution may or may not be best practice, but I do not have any better solution.

I have decided to post my temporary solution if anyone ever finds this question and wonder about a solution.

I am still looking for a typesafe and best practice solution, so if anyone got any answers please post it. I will accept your answer regardless of when you post your solution.

```
class Car {
    Integer id;
    Integer numberOfWheels;
    @JsonIgnore
    Engine engine;

    @JsonProperty("engine")
    public Map<String, Object> getEngineFormatted(){
        return engine == null ? null : engine.getFormatted();
    }
}   

class Engine {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String producer;
    Integer horsePower;
    Integer weight; 

    public Map<String, Object> getFormatted(){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("id", id);
        map.put("name", name);
        map.put("producer", producer);

        return map;
    }
}
```

Car JSON:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "numberOfWheels":4,
  "engine": {
    "id":1,
    "name":"some engine"
    "producer":"some engine producer"
  }
}
```

Engine JSON

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"some engine"
    "producer":"some engine producer"
    "horsePower":250
    "weight":500
}
```