# Failed to serialize object (using Room DB) to json string using Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, android-room

I have a class Item (see below) in which I have used some Room db annotations. It also has a nested class named ItemInfo. Both of these classes have an empty constructor.

The problem is that when I try to serialize an object of Item class, app crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.android.carrymates, PID: 18526
              java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
                  at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:133)
                  at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:119)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.PreJava9ReflectionAccessor.makeAccessible(PreJava9ReflectionAccessor.java:31)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:103)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:85)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter$1.create(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:48)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:696)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
                  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
                  ... more log (irrelevant to question asked)
```

Item.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "items", indices = {@Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true), @Index(value = {"owner", "type"})})
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String id="";

   //...rest fields are int, boolean and String only

    @Embedded
    ItemInfo itemInfo; // see ItemInfo


    public Item() {

   }


    // ...getters and setters

    @IgnoreExtraProperties
    public static class ItemInfo {

        //...fields are int, boolean and String only

        public ItemInfo() {

        }

        //...getters and setters
    }
}
```

My guess is that Room DB annotations are adding at least one object of type `java.lang.reflect.Method` which Gson is unable to serialize.

Below is the code I am using to serialize Item object to json string, where `item` is a object of class Item with non-null values of fields of type `String` and `ItemInfo`.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String result = gson.toJson(item); // crash begins from here
```

How do I address this problem? I expect at least a workaround solution.

Comment: Could you post the serialization code?

Comment: @OlmanCarballoTellez see?

Comment: What type is the `type` field? Is it really just `int`, `boolean`, and `String` fields or are there any types of type `Class` in there too?

Comment: Yes, rest fields are `int`, `boolean` and `String` only.

Comment: String result = gson.toJson(item);
What's in item ?, it must be java objects, for eg 
Car car = new Car();
car.brand = "Rover";
car.doors = 5;

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(car);

Comment: I think the point is the embedded class, is it necessary to declare it static?

Comment: show the embedded class please

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:**

I'm not aware of what **RoomDB** does with `@Entity` classes (though it looks like RoomDB uses subclasses rather than classes written by you).

Also I run the test on JVM

But I can suggest you to use [@Expose](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html):

```
public class GsonTest {

  private static class SampleModel {
    @Expose
    private int i;

    private Method method;

    @Expose
    private Nested nested = new Nested();
  }

  private static class Nested {
    @Expose
    private String a = "my string";
  }

  @Test
  public void failsWithMethodField() throws Exception {
    assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
      SampleModel sampleModel = new SampleModel();
      sampleModel.i = 10;
      sampleModel.method = Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("equals", Object.class);
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      gson.toJson(sampleModel);
    });
  }

  @Test
  public void withExposedDoesNotFail() {
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
      SampleModel sampleModel = new SampleModel();
      sampleModel.method = Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("equals", Object.class);
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
      String json = gson.toJson(sampleModel);
      System.out.println(json); // {"i":0,"nested":{"a":"my string"}}
    });
  }
}
```

The essential part is to configure `Gson` with `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` option:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Then mark all fields that should be used when serializing and deserializing with `@Expose` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

normally i get output when i try this,

```
public class Car { 

    public String brand = null;

    public int    doors = 0;

}


Car car = new Car();

car.brand = "Rover";

car.doors = 5;

Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(car);
```

> checkout this : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use different objects for different goals (storing in a `Room` db and serializing to `json`).

You need to have an interface of your **Item** entity:

```
public interface Item {

    int getId();

    //other fields
}
```

Then you need a specific implementation for a `Room` db entity. What you actually already have, but need make same refactoring:

```
@Entity(tableName = "items", indices = {@Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true), @Index(value = {"owner", "type"})})
public class RoomItem implements Item {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private int id;

    //other fields

    public RoomItem() {
    }

    public RoomItem(Item item) {
        id = item.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //other getters and setters
}
```

Plus you need to get rid of the inner static class **ItemInfo** and make it in a separate `.java` file.

And finally, you need a specific implementation for a `Gson` entity:

```
public class GsonItem implements Item {

    private final int id;

    public GsonItem(Item origin) {
        id = origin.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

In this case, you will able to use it like this without any issues:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String result = gson.toJson(new GsonItem(item));
```

Yes, this approach leads you to write a little bit more code, but lack of unexpected issues like yours definitely cost the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try this please: this code snipped is working properly

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Embedded;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Index;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@Entity(tableName = "items", indices = {@Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true), @Index(value = {"owner", "type"})})
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String id="";

    //...rest fields are int, boolean and String only

    @Embedded
    ItemInfo itemInfo; // see ItemInfo


    public Item() {

    }


    // ...getters and setters

    @IgnoreExtraProperties
    public static class ItemInfo {

        //...fields are int, boolean and String only

        public ItemInfo() {

        }

        int prop1;
        String id="";
        //...getters and setters
    }
}
```

note the dependencies snipped too please

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"

// Arch
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"

implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1';
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1';
```

and the implementation:

```
        Item item = new Item();

        item.id = "Rover";
        item.itemInfo = new Item.ItemInfo();
        item.itemInfo.id = "asd";
        item.itemInfo.prop1 = 1;

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(item); // here json ={"id":"Rover","itemInfo":{"id":"asd","prop1":1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

do not nest these classes, in order to use the `@Embedded` annotation:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "items",
    indices = {
        @Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true), 
        @Index(value = {"owner", "type"})
    }
)
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    String id = null;

    @Embedded
    ItemInfo itemInfo;

    public Item() {

    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "item_info")
public class ItemInfo {

    public ItemInfo() {

    }

    ...
}
```

also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations), concerning `GSON` exclusion strategies (which might be required for `itemInfo`)

or simply add these fields directly into class `Item`, in order to serialize them all at once -

in order not to add more complexity than required, which only cause issues down the road.