# How to use a specific Json Serialize in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, json, gson, jax-rs

I'm using the Gson Library and JAX-rs for a RestFull-API project. This is my endpoint:

```
@POST
@PermitAll
@Path("/search")
public List<Model> listAll(@BeanParam @Valid PageRequest page, SearchModelRequest request) {
    List<Model> models = modelDao.getOrderedByViews(page);
    return models;
}
```

The system automatically serialise the model object with a full JSON with all attributes, but I just want to send some of them; how Can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)

Comment: If you are using a Java EE container, I'd suggest to switch to JSON-B.

Comment: Something with gson?

Answer (score 0):

By default in Gson if you mark the field as transient, it won't be considered in parsing.

e.g.:

```
private transient String name = "";
```

Nevertheless there are more ways to do it as explained in documentation:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization

- Java Modifier Exclusion
- Gson's @Expose
- User Defined Exclusion Strategies