# Boolean in Multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have boolean field:

```
private boolean isReady = false;
private boolean isReady() {
  return isReady;
}
```

and I am using it inside two methods:

```
synchronized (topologyLock)
{
   try 
    {
      while(!instance.isReady()) 
      {
        topologyLock.wait();
      }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {               
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } 

private synchronized boolean topologyChanged()
{           
    synchronized(topologyLock)
    {
        isReady = true;
        topologyLock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

I think that above code should work perfectly - or do I need to make this boolean variable volatile?

Comment: It doesn't need to be volatile if you're only accessing it from synchronized blocks.

Comment: @GhostCat using `synchronized` guarantees `happens-before` relationship, so there is no chance that a cached value would be used if **all** access is from within `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: Unrelated: A) there is no point in having a private method to read a private field. Just dump that method. B) consider not using signal/wait on that low-level. Java has plenty of "high level" abstractions that help you not writing such code.

Comment: @shmosel because it does contain some other code as well which requires lock as well .

Comment: Ok but watch out for deadlock.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your useful comments . As it is a legacy code i don't want to take any chance so keeping it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [stone ages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430757/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-used-for):

> So, when to make a variable volatile?
>
> When you have a variable which can be accessed by many threads and you want every thread to get the latest updated value of that variable even if the value is updated by any other thread/process/outside of the program.

So one could think that `volatile` is necessary here. But (as Kayaman pointed out correctly): it is all about the Java memory model. And the fact that `synchronized` not only prevents **race conditions** (as only one thread can update data at any point in time) but also establishes a **[happens before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108541/happens-before-relationships-with-volatile-fields-and-synchronized-blocks-in-jav)** relation.

Therefore: the above code doesn't have race conditions; and it also makes sure that each thread sees the "correct" value of `isReady`.

Of course, if you ever happen to manipulate `isReady` out of a synchronized block, then all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you are only interacting with it in `synchronized` blocks, which by definition run only on one thread.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the real issue, which is visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that you exported is the only code accessing `isReady`, it is correct.

Instead if this is the only part of code writing `isReady`, you need to define `isReady` as `volatile` to read it correctly from another part of code.

In any case if the relevant synchronized code is the code that you posted, is incorrect defining the method `topologyChanged` as `synchronized` because internally you are using the monitor `topologyLock`. It is enough.