# Is it possible to modify a non-volatile variable such that another thread is able to "see" the update?

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a Thread-X which reads a **non-volatile** variable every second, doing so without any means of synchronization.

Now I was wondering is there some way to modify that non-volatile variable on Thread-Y such that Thread-Y's write would be (eventually) visible on Thread-X ?

```
public class Test {
    private static boolean double = 1; // this variable is
                                             // strictly not volatile

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(variable);
                    try {
                        java.lang.Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                    } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start(); // line 17
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // the task is to change variable to "2" such the write
                // is (eventually) registered by the other threads

                // allowed to use any synchronization/locking techniques
                // required, but line 1 to line 17 must not be changed
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to modify a non-volatile variable such that another thread which reads it without any synchronization techniques (*raw read*) is able to "see" the update eventually?

**Background:**

I need to read a variable from a large number of threads, for an *infinite* amount of times.

From what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), on most cpus (e.g. x86) reads of volatile variables are "almost totally free" but not "totally free".

Now since I have an *infinite* number of reads from an *infinite* number of threads, I would love the variable to be **non-volatile**. However, once in a blue moon the variable needs to be updated. In my use-case, it really doesn't matter how expensive it takes to update that variable, but that update must eventually be readable by the reader-threads.

**Solutions:**

Based on [Tomasz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9580724/632951), I've built this solution and I was wondering is Solution-1 flawed or is it solid?

```
public class Solution1 {
    private static double variable = 1; // this variable is
                                        // strictly not volatile

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(variable);
                    try {
                        java.lang.Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                    } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start(); // line 17
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                variable = 2;
                // writer-thread now terminates,
                // is it guaranteed that when it
                // "terminates successfully", variable
                // is updated on the reader-thread ?
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Based on [Joonas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9580686/632951), I've built this solution and I was wondering is Solution-2 flawed or is it solid?

```
public class Solution2 {
    private static double variable = 1; // this variable is
                                        // strictly not volatile
    private static volatile boolean lock = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(variable);
                    try {
                        java.lang.Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                    } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start(); // line 17
        new java.lang.Thread(new java.lang.Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                variable = 2;
                lock = false; // does this line guarantee
                                // that other threads will now 
                                // see the update to variable (piggypacking)?

                // now let's assume this thread doesn't terminate
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make the variable volatile. That's what it's for. Also, polling is often a poor solution and perhaps there's a cleaner alternative to polling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm using polling to demonstrate the question.. because its rather hard to explain it clearly without an example.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to modify a non-volatile variable such that another thread which reads it without any synchronization techniques (raw read) is able to "see" the update eventually?

**No.** Some synchronization technique must be used, because otherwise the (JIT) compiler is allowed to optimize your line to `System.out.println(false);` (if `false` is the value first seen by that thread). That is, it can optimize *reading* the variable away.

I have no idea how likely it would actually do that, but it's okay according to the Java Memory Model, so your options are:

- `volatile`. This is probably the simplest and lightest option for your case.
- `AtomicBoolean`. Some discussion of it vs. volatile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786825/java-volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876122/volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean).
- `synchronized` block. Overkill in this case.
- `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`. More features than in `synchronized`.
- `Thread.join()`. Not useful in this case (the reading thread would wait for the writer to terminate).
- [Piggybacking.](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_piggyback.shtml) Don't even think about it. Too many things that may and will go wrong.

Just use `volatile` and let the JVM worry about implementing it efficiently. [It's not expensive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866/is-volatile-expensive)

Comment: I'm trying to get "totally free" reads, and I'm prepared to do a very expensive write in exchange for "totally free" reads. Is it true that for this problem, there is no better solution than declaring it as volatile?

Comment: Well. There's a technique called "piggypacking", which is based on the fact that accessing *any* volatile variable synchronizes local copies of *all* cached variables with main memory. Therefore, it is occasionally possible to write to one variable without synchronization and then take advantage of subsequent synchronization on a different variable to ensure that main memory is updated with both variables. [See this for reference](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_piggyback.shtml). It's very brittle and shouldn't be used for anything, but just FYI...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "main memory". When you say "main memory", do you mean the "memory" used by all the threads?

Comment: @Pacerier: Main memory here is the RAM memory of the computer. Cache is the processor cache. The existence of these two memories is the reason why `volatile` is needed in the first place: if all processors would access RAM directly, then there would be no memory / variable visibility issues (but it would be slow). See [What every programmer should know about memory](http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/).

Comment: Btw take a look at the update (solution-2), do you think its solid?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't think the (solution-2) can get around the fact that the JIT compiler is allowed to optimize *reading* of `variable` away, replacing it with a local variable. No amount of writing can fix it, if it's not being read! Using piggypacking correctly and effectively would require *really, really* understanding the JMM, from inside out. I'm not that much an expert. I suggest just using volatile, and then measuring where your bottlenecks are. Otherwise you're quite likely trying to optimize the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm using it for a DEBUG variable, it's read roughly once per method call for 99% of the methods I write. It's not a "static final" because I want it to be changeable dynamically. Imagine there are x number of method calls in the lifecycle of a program, that's x number of reads on the debug variable...

Comment: Btw are you aware if terminating the thread would enforce an update (solution-1) ?

Comment: Just terminating thread B has no effect on thread A. Tomasz is talking about *joining* threads. Sorry, you simply can't get around the fact that the JVM JIT compiler is allowed to optimize *reading* `variable` away unless you're using some synchronization construct (or `Thread.join()`; the *reading* thread must call `join` on the *writing* thread which is about to terminate).

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Synchronization and the Java Memory Model](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html) from [Concurrent Programming in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090) by Doug Lea:

> Changes to fields made by one thread **are guaranteed to be visible** to other threads only under the following conditions:
>
> - A writing thread releases a **synchronization lock** and a reading thread subsequently acquires that same synchronization lock.
> - If a field is declared as **volatile**, any value written to it is flushed and made visible by the writer thread before the writer thread performs any further memory operation (i.e., for the purposes at hand it is flushed immediately). Reader threads must reload the values of volatile fields upon each access.
> - The **first time a thread accesses a field** of an object, it sees either the initial value of the field or a value since written by some other thread.
> - As a **thread terminates**, all written variables are flushed to main memory. For example, if one thread synchronizes on the termination of another thread using Thread.join, then it is guaranteed to see the effects made by that thread (see §4.3.2).

Last two options do not apply to your situations so you need either `volatile` or `synchronized`, sorry. Note that `AtomicInteger.get()` simply returns `volatile` value, so you get nothing except extra layer.

Comment: Regarding point 4, do you mean that if the "writer-thread" terminates, the "reader-thread" will see the update to the **non-volatile** variable, Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Pacerier: well, it's not me, it's Doug Lea ;-). The example mentions `Thread.join()`, I don't think it means "*every change made by terminated thread is immediately visible by all other threads*". Also do you really consider starting new thread just to modify a single variable an option?

Comment: Yes if it works, because for my use-case I seldom need to write, but there's an *infinite* amount of reads from a large number of threads. Now declaring the variable as volatile would penalize all reader threads, and I would rather "heavily penalize" the writer-thread.

Comment: @Pacerier: when it comes to `volatile` read performance, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633866

Comment: Thanks for the link =D Btw take a look at the update (solution-1), do you think its working?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to get "totally free" reads, and I'm prepared to do a very expensive write in exchange for "totally free" reads. Is it true that for this problem, there is no better solution than declaring it as volatile?

Nothing is totally free.  A read of a volatile variable which is not being changed can be sub-nanosecond which may be more than fast enough.  If you read after a write it can take 5 nano-seconds.  The branch could take 5 - 10 nanoseconds regardless of your "free" read and if you do something as simple as taking the time e.g. with System.nanoTime(), this can take 20 - 180 nano-seconds depending on your OS.  The cost your read should be VERY low in your list of concerns.

For example, you should be worried about whether your code is warmed up so it is compiled instead of interpreted. This can make far, far more difference (see below)

---

`volatile` can be needed in a number of situations, but I don't believe you have one of them.

The most common situation is as @Joonas Pulakka mentions where the JIT optimises the field in a manner you don't want i.e. it stops reading the value and makes it a local variable, because its not volatile.

This optimisation can happen after a loop iterates 10,000 times in quick succession.  In your case, it is not quick succession, but over 2.7 hours so the JIT might never optimise the code.