# Multiple threads reading a primitive type

Tags: java, thread-safety, primitive

If multiple threads read a primitive type that has been previously set and does not change ever after, can they get a wrong value?

For example, assume the following simple code excerpt:

```
public static final boolean proceed = read(); // Read the value from a file

public static void doSomething() // Method accessed by multiple threads
{
    if (proceed)
    {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }
}
```

Assuming that the `proceed` variable is initialized to `true`, is it possible that, in one or more of the multiple threads that simultaneously run the `doSomething()` method, the printed message is `FALSE`?

If the `proceed` variable was mutable, surely that would be possible, hence the need for synchronization, or for using an `AtomicBoolean` (e.g., as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501223/when-i-need-to-use-atomicboolean-in-java)). But in this case `proceed` is immutable and only set once, during the static initialization of the containing class.

Similarly for other primitive types, if a value is set as final, it should always be thread-safe to access it afterwards, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your variable is `final` guarantees that all threads will see it in a consistent post-initialisation state. This is applicable to objects' references too (i.e. all threads will see a non null value of the Object if it has been initialised to a non null reference - but if your object is not thread-safe, some threads might see the object itself in an inconsistent or stale state).

ps: that is assuming your read method does not try to read the boolean value in which case it would see the default (false) value.

Answer (score 1):

Since `proceed` is `static` and `final` , it can not be reassigned which turns in to thread-safe.

`static` says it is class level and `final` says it's value can't be changed and this is a `primitive` so defiantly this immutable and hence thread-safe .

Answer (score 1):

You are saying it is immutable `(static and final)`, so we can safely say it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is thread-safe because it's immutable.

If it were mutable, you would need to use the `volatile` keyword to make sure you get the latest value if modified in another thread.

[Do you ever use the volatile keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java)

Comment: Although your comment on double and long is accurate, it does not apply to this question. The same question with a double instead of a boolean would get the same answer.