# Java unable to break out of while loop

Tags: java

I am trying to build a timer in java.

Expected Output:

When you run the program, there's a window with a big "0" in it.

Once the user presses any key from the keyboard, the number increases by 1 every second.

Here's what I have.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

    public class TimerTest implements KeyListener {
        static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 960;
        static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 540;
        static boolean timerStarted;
        static int keyPressedNum; //amount of times the user pressed any key.

        static JLabel label;
        static int currentTime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTest");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        label = new JLabel();
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 256));
        label.setText("0");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.addKeyListener(new TimerTest());

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            while (TimerTest.timerStarted == false) {
                if (TimerTest.timerStarted == true) {break;}
            }

            try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

            currentTime++;
            label.setText(String.valueOf(currentTime));
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Keypress indicated.");
        TimerTest.timerStarted = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

When I press any key, the program sets `timerStarted` as true.

Because `timerStarted` is true, I was expecting this part:

```
    while (TimerTest.timerStarted == false) {
            if (TimerTest.timerStarted == true) {break;}
    }
```

to break out of the loop.

Instead when I run the program and press any key, the command line just prints: `Keypress indicated.`, and it doesn't break out of that loop.

Now here's the weird part:

I tried adding some code to the while block, like this.

```
  while (TimerTest.timerStarted == false) {
        System.out.println("currently stuck here...");
        //(I simply added a println code)
        if (TimerTest.timerStarted == true) {break;}
  }
```

Surprisingly when I do this, the program works just like how I wanted. It breaks out of that loop and the timer runs.

This confuses me. Adding a `System.out.println();` fixes the issue...?

Why does not having `System.out.println()` makes me unable to break out of the loop?

Any explanations would be appreciated =)

Comment: `TimerTest.timerStarted == true` would logically never fall under `TimerTest.timerStarted == false` (unless something infinitesimally unimaginably precise makes a predictable change between the two `if` executions)

Comment: Yes, I know it's pretty much the same thing as not having `TimerTest.timerStarted == true`. However, both cases do not work.

Comment: What is the actual/real condition under which you want to break out of the loop? I see nothing in the loop changing the value of `TimerTest.timerStarted`. Is it being changed outside?

Comment: I want to break out of the loop when `timerStarted` = true.
I used the while loop to "wait" until `timerStarted` is equal to true

Comment: IIRC, a `break` will break out of the nearest loop, not all loops. You have a `while` in your `while`, so when you break out of the inner `while`, you should still be in the outer `while`.

Comment: Are you seeing the `"Keypress indicated."` output when you hit a key (supposing I interpret your code correctly)?

Comment: @dommson, yes I do acknowledge that. the problem is that I am unable to break out of the inner while loop.

Comment: @ernest_k yes, i do see the "Keypress indicated" output in the command prompt.

Comment: I've also tried your code, and it works as I understand you expect it to. It is indeed breaking out of the inner loop when I hit the keyboard. However, the outer loop still continues. I could confirm that by adding different `println` outputs at the beginning of each while loop body

Comment: There is nothing in the code at this time that would allow the outer loop to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is not thread-safe.  Specifically, you are not doing the things that are needed to ensure that reads of `timerStarted` see the most recent write by the other thread.

There are number of possible solutions, including:

- declare `timerStarted` as `volatile`, or
- read and write `timerStarted` in a `synchronized` block, or
- use an `AtomicBoolean`.

These ensure that there is a *happens-before* relation between a write of the flag by one thread and subsequent read by a second thread.  That in turn guarantees that the read sees the value that was written.

> "Why does not having System.out.println() makes me unable to break out of the loop?"

Because there is no *happens-before* relationship; see above.

A more interesting question is:

> "Why does it work when you add the println?"

The `System.out.println()` does some synchronization under the hood.  (The stream object is thread-safe, and synchronizes to ensure that its data structures don't get messed up.)  This is *apparently* sufficient to cause writes to `timerStarted` to be flushed to main memory.

However, this is not guaranteed.  The javadocs do not specify the synchronization behavior for the `println` call.  Furthermore, it is not clear that this is sufficient to give a (serendipitous!) *happens before* between the write and read of `timerStarted`.

References:

- [Memory Consistency Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)
- [How to understand happens-before consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970428/how-to-understand-happens-before-consistent)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you are using a non **thread-safe** `boolean` variable `timerStarted`

moreover the `while(true)` loop is running from main thread but the modification you do on `timerStarted` is done from another thread this gives unexpected behavior completely depends on the machine that runs the program.

This situation is making a race-condition between changing value of `timerStarted` and checking for that change

**How did I detected this:**

Simply I printed the thread id while checking for value changes and while modifying the value

**The solution**

check these code changes

```
static AtomicBoolean timerStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

and

```
   while (Scratch.timerStarted.get() == false) {
        System.out.println("Thread.ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ----> Scratch.timerStarted: " + Scratch.timerStarted);
        if (Scratch.timerStarted.get() == true) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Keypress indicated.");
        Scratch.timerStarted.set(true);
        System.out.println("Thread.ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ----> Scratch.timerStarted: " + Scratch.timerStarted);
    }
```

here I used `AtomicBoolean` instead of `boolean` which is thread safe.

---

What you need to read about:

1. Multi-threading in java (check this: https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java)
2. `AtmoicBoolean` vs boolean (check this: [When do I need to use AtomicBoolean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501223/when-do-i-need-to-use-atomicboolean-in-java))