# Java volatile variable doesn't behave correctly.

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

```
public class MyThread
{
    volatile static int i;

    public static class myT extends Thread
    {
        public void run ()
        {
            int j = 0;
            while(j<1000000){
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] argv)
    throws InterruptedException{
            i = 0;

            Thread my1 = new myT();
            Thread my2 = new myT();
            my1.start();
            my2.start();

            my1.join();
            my2.join();

            System.out.println("i = "+i);
    }
}
```

Since volatile builds happens-before relationship, the final value of i should be strictly 2000000. However, the actual result is nothing different from being without volatile for variable i. Can anyone explanation why it doesn't work here? Since i is declared volatile, it should be protected from memory inconsistency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can anyone explanation why it doesn't work here? Since i is declared volatile, it should be protected from memory inconsistency.

It is protected but unfortunately `i++` is not an atomic operation.  It is actually read/increment/store.  So `volatile` is not going to save you from the race conditions between threads.  You might get the following order of operations from your program:

1. thread #1 reads `i`, gets 10
2. right afterwards, thread #2 reads `i`, gets 10
3. thread #1 increments `i` to 11
4. thread #2 increments `i` to 11
5. thread #1 stores 11 to `i`
6. thread #2 stores 11 to `i`

As you can see, even though 2 increments have happened and the value has been properly synchronized between threads, the race condition means the value only went up by 1.  See this [nice looking explanation](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html).  Here's another good answer: [Is a volatile int in Java thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805192/is-a-volatile-int-in-java-thread-safe)

What you should be using are `AtomicInteger` which allows you to safely increment from multiple threads.

```
static final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
...
        for (int j = 0; j<1000000; j++) {
            i.incrementAndGet();
        }
```

Comment: Only `i` needs to be an `AtomicInteger`; `j` is purely local to the thread.

Comment: Then what's the point of declaring i as volatile? Since it's not protected anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer @OneZero.  Declaring it as `volatile` won't work because ++ is not atomic.  You could synchronize on it every time you update it or use `AtomicInteger`.  Making it `volatile` isn't enough.

Comment: @OneZero http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html should explain a bit about what `volitile` is for.  Not this.

Comment: What's the difference between a volatile read and a regular read? Just for the single read step. Aren't they just the same thing?

Comment: A `volatile` read crosses a memory barrier and guarantees that you get the most up-to-date value.  A "normal" read has no such guarantees. See here: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html

Comment: @OneZero a non-volitile read can get some bits for the pre-write value, and others from a post-write value, but only for types larger than a `word` on the underlying memory.  `double` is the most common offender.  Generally speaking, most concurrency issues are too much for `volatile` so look at `synchronize` and `wait` instead.

Comment: @Gray In practice on anything build this millenium, probably true.  I don't think the guarantee is in the language spec, though.  Perhaps a more practical guarantee is that write-order is preserved, so if you have a `double data` and a `volitile boolean ready` and code that sets `data` first and `ready = true` second, it is certain that after you see `ready` turn to true, `data` will also have been set, even in a different thread.  This is not guaranteed without the `volatile` keyword, where you can see `ready` true and then the value of `data` may not have propagated from the write thread.

Comment: I think for ARM (ie, smartphones), volatile reads are significantly more expensive than non-volatile reads (they're pretty close on x86), so presumably they're not the same.

Comment: Certainly @yshavit.  Typically `volatile` reads and writes are 1 to 2 orders of magnitude slower because of the memory synchronization and optimization impact.

Comment: @Gray From what I understand, on x86, a volatile read is almost exactly as cheap as a non-volatile -- it's the writes that cost you. I haven't tested that myself, but I read it in reputable places such as the java concurrency-interest list. On ARM, I think it's the opposite -- writes are cheap, but reads are expensive.

Comment: That is not true @yshavit.  I've done performance tests.  1 to 2 orders of magnitude slower.  You _always_ pay for the memory synchronization.

Comment: @Gray They get much worse under heavy contention -- maybe that's what you saw? E.g. http://brooker.co.za/blog/2012/09/10/volatile.html