# Why is this class not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
class ThreadSafeClass extends Thread
{
     private static int count = 0;

     public synchronized static void increment()
     {
         count++;
     }

     public synchronized void decrement()
     {
         count--;
     }
}
```

Can anyone explain why above class is not thread safe?

Comment: I don't know about Java, but it looks like each of those methods are *individually* thread-safe, but you could have a thread in **each** of the methods at the same time. Maybe if you have a single method which takes a bool (`increment`) it'd be thread safe. Or if you used some locking object. As I said, I don't know about Java - my comment stems from C# knowledge.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805192/is-a-volatile-int-in-java-thread-safe

Comment: I also don't know Javavery well, but to synchronize access to a static variable, the `synchronized` should be used only in static methods. So in my opionion even if you removes the `increment` method, it's still not threadsafe since two instances (which have only synchronized access through the same instance) can call the method concurrently.

Comment: It is thread safe as long as you never create an instance of the class.

Comment: Why do you think it is not thread safe.

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear to me, though probably not deserving of as many votes as it received (maybe it was in the Hot Network Questions).  (Presumably the asker thought it's not thread-safe because someone (or an IDE/tool) told him it isn't, but not why.)

Comment: why increment is static and decrement is not?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Since the `increment` method is `static` it will synchronize on the class object for the `ThreadSafeClass`. The `decrement` method is not static and will synchronize on the instance used to call it. I.e., they will synchronize on different objects and thus two different threads can execute the methods at the same time. Since the `++` and `--` operations are not atomic the class is not thread safe.

Also, since `count` is `static`, modifying it from `decrement` which is a synchronized *instance* method is unsafe since it can be called on different instances and modify `count` concurrently that way.

Comment: You may add, since `count` is `static`, having an instance method `decrement()` is wrong, even if there was no `static` `increment()` method, as two threads can invoke `decrement()` on different instances modifying the same counter concurrently.

Comment: That's possibly a good reason to prefer using `synchronized` blocks in general (even on the whole method content) instead of using the modifier on the method, i.e. `synchronized(this) { ... }` and `synchronized(ThreadSafeClass.class) { ... }`.

Comment: [`++` and `--` are not atomic, even on `volatile int`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7805212/1986871). `Synchronized` takes care of the read/update/write problem with `++`/`--`, but the `static` keyword is, well, *key* here. Good answer!

Comment: Re, _modifying [a static field] from...a synchronized instance method is wrong_:  There is nothing inherently wrong with accessing a static variable from within an instance method, and there is nothing inherently wrong with accessing it from a `synchronized` instance method either.  Just don't expect "synchronized" on the instance method to provide protection for the static data. The only problem here is what you said in your first paragraph:  The methods use different locks in an attempt to protect the same data, and that of course provides no protection at all.

Answer (score 23):

You have two synchronized methods, but one of them is static and the other is not. When accessing a synchronized method, based on it's type (static or non-static), a different object will be locked. For a static method, a lock will be put on the Class object, while for the non-static block, a lock will be put on the instance of the class that runs the method. Because you have two different locked objects, you can have two threads that modify the same object simultaneously.

Answer (score 14):

> Can anyone explain why above class is not thread safe?

- `increment` being static, synchronization will be done on the class itself.
- `decrement` being not static, synchronization will be done on the object instantiation, but that doesn't secure anything as `count` is static.

I'd like to add that to declare a thread-safe counter, I believe the simplest way is to use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of a primitive int.

Let me redirect you to the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package-info.

Answer (score 8):

Others' answers are pretty good explained the reason. I just add something to summarize `synchronized`:

```
public class A {
    public synchronized void fun1() {}

    public synchronized void fun2() {}

    public void fun3() {}

    public static synchronized void fun4() {}

    public static void fun5() {}
}

A a1 = new A();
```

`synchronized` on `fun1` and `fun2` is synchronized on instance object level. `synchronized` on `fun4` is synchronized on class object level. Which means:

1. When 2 threads call `a1.fun1()` at same time, latter call will be blocked.
2. When thread 1 call `a1.fun1()` and thread 2 call `a1.fun2()` at same time, latter call will be blocked.
3. When thread 1 call `a1.fun1()` and thread 2 call `a1.fun3()` at same time, no blocking, the 2 methods will be executed at same time.
4. When thread 1 call `A.fun4()`, if other threads call `A.fun4()` or `A.fun5()` at same time, latter calls will be blocked since `synchronized` on `fun4` is class level.
5. When thread 1 call `A.fun4()`, thread 2 call `a1.fun1()` at same time, no blocking, the 2 methods will be executed at same time.

Answer (score 6):

1. `decrement` is locking on a different thing to `increment` so they do not prevent each other from running.
2. Calling `decrement` on one instance is locking on a different thing to calling `decrement` on another instance, but they are affecting the same thing.

The first means that overlapping calls to `increment` and `decrement` could result in a cancel-out (correct), an increment or a decrement.

The second means that two overlapping calls to `decrement` on different instances could result in a double decrement (correct) or a single decrement.

Answer (score 4):

Since two different methods, one is instance level and other is class level, so you need to lock on 2 different objects to make it ThreadSafe

Answer (score 1):

As explained in other answers, your code is ***not Thread safe*** since static method `increment()` locks Class monitor and  non-static method `decrement()` locks Object monitor.

For this code example, better solution exists without `synchronzed` keyword usage. 
You have to use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)  to achieve Thread safety.

Thread safe using `AtomicInteger`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class ThreadSafeClass extends Thread {

    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void increment() {
        count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static void decrement() {
        count.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public static int value() {
        return count.get();
    }

}
```