# Volatile key was not working as expected

Tags: java

Am writing sample app to understand volatile behavior.
According to me the value of this variable should change to `50` but the output I'm getting is `10`.

Main method:

```
public class Volatile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShareObj so = new ShareObj();
        Thread1 t1 =  new Thread1(so);
        Thread2 t2 =  new Thread2(so);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(so.a);
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
class ShareObj {
    public volatile int a =10; 
}

class Thread1 extends Thread {
    ShareObj so;
    Thread1(ShareObj so) {
        this.so  = so;
    }
    public void run() {
        so.a += 10;
        System.out.println(so.a);
    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread {
    ShareObj so;
    Thread2(ShareObj so) {
        this.so=so;
    }
    public void run() {
        so.a+=10;
        System.out.println(so.a);
    }
}
```

The output I'm expecting is `50` but it is `10`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For one thing, your threads probably haven't run a single statement by the time `main` runs `System.out.println(so.a);` (because starting a thread is slower than printing something)

Comment: Why do you expect 50?

Comment: Note in this example you'll likely get the same result with or without volatile, in practice.

Comment: Also, realistically, if you *ever* think you need to use `volatile`, then there's a 99% chance you have a race condition somewhere (unrelated to `volatile`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. As @immibis and @Beri already pointed out, your `System.out.println(so.a);` in your `main` method will probably run before your threads are finished.
2. You start `a` at `10` and have two threads which increment it by `10` each, so you should expect `30` instead of `50`.

After changing your `main` method to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ShareObj so = new ShareObj();
    Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(so);
    Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(so);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(so.a);
}
```

the code prints out `30` as expected (as last line; note that both of the threads might output `20` *or* `30`, so you shouldn't rely on the first two outputs).

I would also like to recommend [@user3707125's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002069/4616087), pointing out that `volatile` might still not produce the expected results (when you have more threads and/or more incrementing steps) - cf. also [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805192/is-a-volatile-int-in-java-thread-safe).

Answer (score 4):

First you need to wait for both threads to finish, before printing their results.

```
...
t1.start();
t2.start();
t1.join(); // this will make main thread to wait untill thread is finished
t2.join();
.....
```

Currently, you are stating two threads, but before any of them could change volatile value, your main thread is pring value and exiting.

Docs are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am considering that the code you provided is simplified, and you used debug execution in order to assure that both threads completed their job when `System.out.println` call was made, otherwise you should use `Thread.join` before printing the result.

Now regarding `volatile` keyword. `volatile` means that there would be no thread cache for this variable. However it doesn't mean that actions with this variable will be performed atomically.

The code `so.a += 10` if simplified means nothing more than `so.a = so.a + 10`, this operation is performed in two steps by the JVM (lets omit the field access for simplicity):

1. Compute `so.a + 10`
2. Assign `so.a` to the result of computation

Now lets analyze how it may affect the execution (image that next case occurred):

1. thread_1: compute and put on stack (so.a + 10) => 0 + 10 => 10 (x)
2. thread_2: compute and put on stack (so.a + 10) => 0 + 10 => 10 (y)
3. thread_1: assign `so.a` from stack => `so.a = x` => `so.a = 10`
4. thread_2: assign `so.a` from stack => `so.a = y` => `so.a = 10`
5. main_thread: print `so.a` => `print(10)`

So it is not safe to use the code that your wrote, even with the `volatile` keyword.

If you want to verify this case change the thread code to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    so.a += 1;
}
```

And you would see that the result is always different and almost never 2kkk.