# How does volatile make my class thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a class

```
public class X {
    private volatile int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Is it thread-safe or not? I think it does not thread-safe even if I add  `volatile` keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7805192/4121347

Comment: Why do you think it is not thread safe? What issues can you see with multiple threads calling the methods on your class? Post a scenario whereby the outcome is incorrect.

Comment: I think JVM makes some optimisations and it does not guarantee the order of line invocation.

Comment: @Finkelson and which lines could the compiler/jit rearrange in this `class` **without changing code semantics**?

Comment: `this.value = value;`

Comment: @Finkelson and what could it rearrange that to, again, without changing semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread-safety can be expressed like "if the object of the class behaves exactly in the same way in multithreaded environment as in single-threaded environment, then it is thread-safe", or maybe instead "behaves exactly as" we could say "behaves correctly".

In your case correct behavior means that after calling `setValue(N)`, a following `getValue()` returns `N`. In case you wouldn't use the `volatile` modifier, this would be true only in single-threaded environment: if you call `setValue(N)` on Thread1 then after you call `getValue()` on Thread2, then it won't necessarily return `N`. The problem is that Thread1 and Thread2 may be executed on separate CPU cores, and CPU cores usually don't read/write directly the shared memory: the two processors can have separate CPU caches, and the `setValue(N)` call may modify only the CPU-cached copy of the value member, therefore this change won't be immediately visible for the RAM. Furthermore, even if `N` is already available in the shared memory, the `getValue()` may read a cached - but obsolete - value from the second processor cache. Therefore the value change you perform on Thread1 may not be immediately visible on Thread2, so `getValue()` may return a deprecated value.

The volatile modifier solves it with its following 2 properties:

- after writing a volatile value it won't only be stored in the CPU cache, but immediately flushed into the shared RAM
- reading a volatile value will always read it from the memory, never from the CPU cache.

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question: you should use volatile when the variable will be accessed by multiple threads and you don't want/need to lock it. From the example your provided the `get` may present a problem in terms of 'thread safe' (see answer of erosb)

As extra: the usage of volatile is limited so I would strongly suggest you to use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) which provides you both atomicity and volatility (AtomicInteger class stores its value field in a volatile variable).