# How to increase the number in a class variable in Java every time I make a new object?

Tags: java

I have a class of Orders and it has the number of the order, and it has to increase by 1 every time a new order is created.

I tried to use static but it changed the number of all the orders

Any help?

Comment: Do you need something like ID generator?

Comment: You need two fields - a `static` one that stores the number of objects you've created, and a non-static one that stores the id of each object.  The constructor assigns the value of the `static` field to the non-static one.  You also need to think about whether your program will be multi-threaded, because the thread-safe version of this is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ID generator you need, there is simple solution with combination of static + instance variable

```
public class Order {
  private static volatile long nextId = 0L;
  private long id;

  public Order (){
    id = nextId++;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I'll just leave it here for reference [Is a volatile int in Java thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805192/is-a-volatile-int-in-java-thread-safe)

Comment: This is not thread-safe.  An increment of a `volatile` variable is two separate memory operations.  That's not atomic.  You either need to use a mutex, or an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @StephenC assuming thread safety is a requirement, of course.  But since this is the second time today that this question has been asked, it's more likely a classroom exercise, for a class that haven't yet learnt about threads.

Comment: That is true.  We don't know if thread-safety is a requirement.  But if it isn't then the `volatile` is not necessary.  In short, in this context `volatile` is EITHER unnecessary OR insufficient.

Comment: @StephenC you are absolutely right (as you so often are).

Comment: It is my goal to be often right :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe like that?

```
public class Order {
  private long id;

  public Order (long lastId){
    id = lastId++;
  }
}
```

so, when you create a new you do  `Order order = new Order(otherOrder);`

Comment: This is wrong. Where is the caller of the constructor going to get the correct parameter value from? And note that the `lastId++` only changes the local variable. The value of `otherOrder` does not change.  Java method parameters are call-by-value!!