# AtomicBoolean vs volatile

Tags: java, boolean, atomic, volatile

In a book on programming I read:

> For “infinite” loops, there should be some way to tell the thread that
>   it is no longer needed, such as via an AtomicBoolean flag

What if instead of `AtomicBoolean` it had had `volatile boolean`? What negative efects are eliminated by having `AtomicBoolean` as opposed to `volatile boolean` for the case above?

If we use the variable exclusively as a flag for thread termination, is there still a difference between `AtomicBoolean` and `volatile` `boolean`?

Comment: There's [a very good description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787435/1590950)

Comment: Not really, I don't think it's a dup. I'm asking regarding the specific scenario of thread terminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a `AtomicBoolean` all read and write actions are atomic (as the name includes). with a `volatile boolean` you still have to deal with race conditions, when two threads accessing the variable at the same time.

Comment: If I'm only using that flag to set/determine thread termination condition, is there still a difference?

Comment: if only one Thread at a time is writing to it and it is okay to maybe finish one interation later, you will have no problems using a `volatile boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific implementation details of your loop *and* the external event setting said stop flag. In practice *volatile* is sufficient if you can ensure that there is only *one* thread updating the volatile. Example:

```
volatile boolean alive = true;

void loop() {
     while (alive) {
     }
}

void stop() {
    alive = false;
}
```

Thats perfectly fine, since there is only *one* possible state transition from true to false.

As soon as is gets a little more complicated (e.g. AtomicInteger reflecting the loops state) you will need compareAndSet() style operations to properly implement the state transitions of the variable.

Example:

```
volatile int state = NOT_STARTED;

void loop() {
    state = RUNNING;
    while (state == RUNNING) {
    }
    state = TERMINATED;
}

void stop() {
    state = ABORT;
}
```

This would possibly *miss* a stop signal if stop() is called before "state = RUNNING" executes, so here compareAndSet is needed to avoid accidentially overwriting ABORT with RUNNING.

Answer (score 1):

I think compare-and-set and getAndSet  operation isn't atomic with volatile variables. Also check the description given by teto [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786825/volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean/3787435#3787435)

Comment: Indeed, I don't see the requirement of an atomic compare-and-set operation when used as a flag that should stop a loop on a different thread, if the case is ThreadA that should stop ThreadB.