# How to ignore or disable the first query snapshot of addSnapshotListener in firestore for android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Android when you call `addSnapshotListener`,
I want to get only changed data.

Firestore provides `snapshots.getDocumentChanges()` but

> The first query snapshot contains added events for all existing
>   documents that match the query

*. as mentioned in the official doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

In my case, I don't want the all existing document matching the query. I just want the changed document.
I want to ignore or disable the first query snapshot

Here is my code:

```
 mDb.collection("conversation_log").document(room_id).collection("messages").orderBy("sent_at")
                                    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {


                                        @Override
                                        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value2, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {.....
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@stle/firebase-firestore-initial-payload-with-onsnapshot-6471c06888c5) someone posted a solution but I wanted this in android.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Mamo but the solution to that question doesn't satisfy my requirement. I have to show notification so comparing the time doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Someone has drafted a solution in jquery/node js, I just wanted if it can be done in android as well, I have the link above in my question