# Firestore does not notify REMOVED change type when querying documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying only new documents on Firestore collection:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference collectionReference = firestore.collection("my_data");


EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = (snapshots, e) -> {

        if (e != null || snapshots == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            if (dc == null) {
                continue;
            }


           

            switch (dc.getType()) {

                case ADDED:

                    onDocumentAdded(dc.getDocument());

                    break;

                case MODIFIED:

                    onDocumentModified(dc.getDocument());

                    break;

                case REMOVED:

                    onDocumentRemoved(dc.getDocument());

                    break;
            }
        }


        // Last event call time 
        SharedPreferences prefs = App.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("firestore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("last_event_call_time", new Date().getTime());
        editor.apply();
    };
```

And I have a method responsible for registering the listener:

```
 /**
 * Register the event listener to query new documents, updates and removes only from the last event call time
 */
public void registerListener(ThreadTaskExecutor executor) {

    if (listenerRegistration != null) {
        return;
    }


    SharedPreferences prefs = MyApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("firestore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Date time = new Date(prefs.getLong("last_event_call_time", new Date().getTime()));

    listenerRegistration = collectionReference
            .orderBy("timestamp")
            .startAt(new Timestamp(time))
            .addSnapshotListener(executor, eventListener);
}

/**
 * Removes the event listener
 */
public void removeListener() {
    if (listenerRegistration == null) {
        return;
    }
    listenerRegistration.remove();
    listenerRegistration = null;
}
```

I have also methods for creating, updating and deleting documents:

```
public void add(String documentId, Map<String, Object> data) throws Exception {

      
        data.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
      
        Tasks.await(collectionReference.document(documentId).set(data));
    }

    public void update(String documentId, Map<String, Object> data) throws Exception {

        data.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

        Tasks.await(collectionReference.document(documentId).update(data));
    }

    public void delete(String documentId) throws Exception {
        delete(collectionReference.document(documentId));
    }

    public void delete(DocumentReference docRef) throws Exception {
        Tasks.await(docRef.delete());
    }
```

My executor (used in this example):

```
public static class ThreadTaskExecutor implements Executor {

        @Override
        public synchronized void execute(Runnable command) {
            new Thread(command).start();
        }
    }
```

Well, I have an app (using this code) installed on two devices, device A and device B.

I open the app in both devices and the event listener is registered.

When I create something on device A, device B is notified (good).
When I update something on device A, device B is also notified (great).
When I remove something on device A, device B is notified as well (awsome).

However ...

If I stop the app process on device B (and it forces the listener to be removed):

If I create something on device A, open the app on device B (listener registered), ADDED event is delivered.

If I update something on device A, open the app on device B (listener registered), ADDED event is delivered as well (weird, but I could work around it).

**Here is the problem:**

**If I delete something on device A, open the app on device B (listener registered), REMOVED event is not delivered at all, so I could not apply this change on device B.**

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for these events is that they signal the changes to the previous state of this listener.

`ADDED` vs `CHANGED`: When you add the listener, every document is new to it, so it fires `ADDED` events for each of them.

`REMOVED`: when you add the listener after deleting a document, there is no knowledge of that document left in the database, so there's no information to fire such an event anymore.

It's important to realize that Firestore synchronizes state, not state changes. Which is for example why you don't get `REMOVED` for those documents, but it also means you may miss state changes that cancel each other out.

If you want to synchronize state changes, you should store those changes in the database. For example, to ensure that your clients know of the document that was deleted, write a `DELETED` status into the document rather than actually deleting it.