# Firestore reduce reads

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to reduce reading from FireStore. if, when a new data is added, it should only fetch that data. I don't want it to read the whole database again. I think this would be unnecessary and costly.
I tried the code below but it doesn't work, it doesn't pull any data

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e

```
    query.get(CACHE).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                boolean isEmpty = task.getResult().isEmpty();
                if (isEmpty) {
                    query.get(SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                Item item= documentSnapshot.toObject(Item.class);
                                items.add(item);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                }
        }
    });
```

And when i try other method, reads data in memory when offline but reloads all database when online.
thank you in advance for any of suggestions.

```
                query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                         for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                Item blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(Item.class);
                                items.add(blogPost);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                         }
                        
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a get() call, you are always getting the online version of the documents from the Firebase servers. If you only want to get what's new, you should consider [tracking the changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). In this way, you can get only the data the corresponds to a specific operation.

But remember that there is no way you can skip the initial data. I have answered a question regarding this topic too:

- [How to skip initial data and trigger only new updates in Firestore Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156109/how-to-skip-initial-data-and-trigger-only-new-updates-in-firestore-firebase/53156370#53156370)

Comment: Snapshotlistener not working as i want. Reloads the all database when the disconnected or the application is exited. I tried to do as in Your article. can you show code sample?  Thank you for Your answer though

Comment: What exactly have you tried from that article and doesn't work the way you expect?