# Does QuerySnapshot only returns added/updated/removed documents or all documents from Firestore in kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

1. Does `QuerySnapshot` only return added/updated/removed documents or all documents, not only updated ones, from Firestore?
2. If it returns all the documents, then is there any way to get only newly added/updated/removed documents?
3. What is the difference between `getDocuments()` and `getDocumentChanges()` in Firestore's `QuerySnapshot` and when to use them?
4. In the below code, is it returning all documents or only added/modified/removed documents? Because It's like we are getting all documents and then sorting them according to their state. Is it correct?

   ```
       .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
           if (e != null) {
               Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e)
               return@addSnapshotListener
           }
       for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
               when (dc.type) {
                   DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> Log.d(TAG, "New city:${dc.document.data}")
                   DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: ${dc.document.data}")
                   DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: ${dc.document.data}")
               }
           }
       }
   ```

**Edit:**

Here is my code

```
.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    cancel(
                        message = "Error fetching posts",
                        cause = error
                    )
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                if (value != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "main value: ${value.size()}")
                    for (dc in value.documents) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "dc ${dc.data}")
                    }

                    offer(reaction)
                }

            }
```

Initially, when the app is open I am getting all documents and it's ok. But when I am modifying one document still I am getting all documents(`Log.d(TAG, "main value: ${value.size()}")`answer is 2. I have a total of 2 documents right now so I am getting both documents modified and not modified). Means first I will get All documents and then I will sort them by using `getDocumentChanges()`.

My code is in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does `QuerySnapshot` only return added/updated/removed documents or all documents(not only updated ones) from Firestore?

A [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) object contains all the results of a Firestore query. So if you perform a query in Firestore, all the results that are returned can be found in the `QuerySnapshot` object.

> 2. If it returns all the documents then is there any way to get only newly added/updated/removed documents?

Yes, there is. You use an [addSnapshotListener(EventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) to listen for updates in real-time. This means that can always [view changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). So you can be notified if a document is only added, modified, or removed. But please also note, that there is no way you can [skip the initial retrieval of the documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156109/how-to-skip-initial-data-and-trigger-only-new-updates-in-firestore-firebase/53156370#53156370).

> 3. What is the difference between `getDocuments()` and `getDocumentChanges()` in Firestore's QuerySnapshot and when to use them?

The [getDocuments()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#getDocuments()) method:

> Returns the documents in this QuerySnapshot as a List in order of the query.

While [getDocumentChanges()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#getDocumentChanges()) method:

> Returns the list of documents that changed since the last snapshot.

So each method does a different operation.

**Edit:**

> 4. In the below code, is it returning all documents or only added/modified/removed documents? Because It's like we are getting all documents and then sorting them according to their state. Is it correct?

It will get **all** documents when you are first opening the app, and unfortunately, this behavior cannot be changed. Right after that, each method will fire according to the performed operation. For example, if a document is added, you'll only get **a single** document in the `${dc.document.data}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am confused about 2nd question's answer. I edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Once again I updated my question with more details. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior since you are getting **all** documents and **not** only the ones that have changed using [view changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), right?

Comment: You have to check that in `DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: ${dc.document.data}")`.

Comment: Ok Got it. Originally we will get all the documents. `DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: ${dc.document.data}")` is just to get more specific document. Thank you for clearing doubt.