# What is the proper getter and setter for java atomic properties

Tags: java, atomic, getter-setter

I have an atomic boolean property in Java

```
private AtomicBoolean endOfInputDataSet;
```

What are the proper getter and setter of this property and what are the consequences of each choice? I can return the `AtomicBoolean` directly

```
public AtomicBoolean getEndOfInputDataSet() {
    return this.endOfInputDataSet;
}

public void setEndOfInputDataSet(AtomicBoolean endOfInputDataSet) {
    this.endOfInputDataSet = endOfInputDataSet;
}
```

or I can return the unwrapped `boolean`:

```
public boolean getEndOfInputDataSet() {
    return this.endOfInputDataSet.get();
}

public void setEndOfInputDataSet(boolean endOfInputDataSet) {
    this.endOfInputDataSet.set(endOfInputDataSet);
}
```

I think the latter solution is just simpler for using by the client and cleaner, but why is it not default when IntelliJ generates the getter and setter?

Comment: It really depends on what you'll use it for. Why is it an AtomicBoolean (not just a boolean), and how will your class's consumers interact with it?

Comment: A standard getter and setter return/set the value of a field. That's why IDEA generates that code.

Comment: @yshavit it's atomic because there are many threads reading and processing the input items and when it's end of input they won't pick the input items anymore. The consumers will set the variable to true/false depending on the state of the input, and any consumer can do it, and I want to avoid data race.

Comment: Could any consumer change it back to false after another has changed it to true, and if so, how do you deal with that race condition? Do you actually need an AtomicBoolean, or would a `volatile boolean` work? This question just seems very hard to answer as written, since there are use cases for both approaches, and you haven't provided enough information to let us know what your situation is. If both approaches work, then that's not really a question for this site, since it's subjective: https://codereview.stackexchange.com may be a better fit.

Comment: @yshavit it's interesting, I will read more about volatile vs. atomic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786825/volatile-boolean-vs-atomicboolean). Anyway, maybe it's one of those questions *what is the best practice* which cannot be objectively answered. In such case let's close it. I don't have any specific use case in mind, I just made it up on the fly. I thought there is one and only universal solution but maybe there isn't.

Comment: Using a `volatile` primitive and using a `final`  `Atomic…` object are two ways to accomplish the same goal: Ensuring visibility of a single value across threads. I prefer the `Atomic…` as its `get`/`set` method calls reminds the programmers across all relevant code that we must be thinking of thread-safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Share the `Atomic…` object container, not its payload value.

```
public final AtomicBoolean endOfInputDataSet = new AtomicBoolean( false ) ;
```

#### *Do* share access to `AtomicBoolean` object

For multiple threads to coordinate around the value contained in the payload of an `Atomic…` object, the threads must have simultaneous direct access to the `Atomic…` object itself.

#### *Do not* share copies of the value within the `AtomicBoolean`

Emitting copies of the value to the various threads breaks the atomic nature of the interaction intended by use of `Atomic…` class. Making copies of the payload’s value is *not* thread-safe, with the threads now unable to coordinate around a single value.

### Details

> private AtomicBoolean endOfInputDataSet;

Make that `final` to prevent another `AtomicBoolean` object from being assigned to replace the original.

And you might as well instantiate in the declaration.

```
private final AtomicBoolean endOfInputDataSet = new AtomicBoolean( … ) ;
```

> return this.endOfInputDataSet;

The Atomic… objects are containers that carry a payload while providing thread-safe access to that payload.

This line returns a reference to that container. The calling programmer may then get or set the content of that payload.

> this.endOfInputDataSet = endOfInputDataSet;

This line ruins your scenario. You enable the calling programmer to replace your container.

> return this.endOfInputDataSet.get();

This line returns a copy of the content of your container.

Be aware  that this line‘s method is returning “old news”. There is a beat of time between the end of the `get()` call and the moment when the calling programmer actually receives the value. During that beat, another thread may have executed a `set` on the atomic container, changing the content of the container. You have undone the “Atomic” in `AtomicBoolean`. This code is *not* thread-safe.

And there are further beats of time between (a) the calling method receiving our returned copy of the payload’s value and (b) the calling method making use of that value. During these additional beats the calling actual payload in the `AtomicBoolean` object could be changing.

> this.endOfInputDataSet.set(endOfInputDataSet);

This line is non-atomic and thread-unsafe in the same way as the line above it.

> why is it not default when IntelliJ generates the getter and setter?

Because such code is ***not* thread-safe**.

When trying to coordinate multiple threads around a single value, those threads must all be dealing simultaneously with the very same value, the value carried as the payload within the atomic wrapper. To accomplish that, all the threads must be dealing with the atomic wrapper container directly.

So, you don’t really need getter/setter accessor methods here. Just make the atomic object `final` and directly accessible (`public` etc.).

Think of a bunch of kids in a classroom trying to coordinate their activity around a message in an envelope. If you let various kids copy that message while other kids are changing the message, you have chaos. To coordinate the kids’ activity, they must be simultaneously viewing the one and only message carried in that envelope.

Comment: This answer makes assumptions about the overall system that I don't think we know. For example, if the idea is that once you change the boolean to true, you should never set it to false again, then I wouldn't expose the AtomicBoolean directly. Instead, provide a method like `markEndOfInput()` that internally uses the AtomicBoolean's compareAndSet. More generally: an AtomicBoolean has a relatively broad API footprint, and by exposing it directly, you're broadening your class's API footprint. Whether that's a good tradeoff is really context-dependent.