# Storing a value for all the instances of a given class

Tags: java

I have a class called *Foo* which in some of its methods relies on a value *globalTime* that depends on time. To simplify it let's say it's a long integer storing the number of seconds since the program started. Now, I want all the instances of *Foo* to share the exact same value for *globalTime*. I, of course could create another class which stores the value and make all the instances of *Foo* retrieve the value for that class but I was just wondering: Is there a way I could do this from within the class?

I'm looking for something like an static field but being able to change its value, although it's stored only once, not once for every instance, and thus every instance from that class would share the same value for that field.

I'm just curious about whether something like this exists in Java, I'm not saying it's a better or worse practice than any other alternative, so please do not discuss the "purpose" of wanting to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with a static field? You can change its value, as long as it's not final.

Comment: `static` doesn't mean readonly. (That would roughly be `final`.)

Comment: Yes, i was confused, I don't know why I could've thought for so long that static methods were read-only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already been told to make a static field. The answer is right.

Note these things also to clear it:

1. `static` fields are associated with the classes. Creating or
   destroying objects does not have any impact on static field.
2. A `static` field remains for the scope of the class not the object.
3. static fields are accessed using `ClassName.fieldName`.

that is why creating object does not have any impact on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a static field for that. Value of static fields can very well be changed just as the value of usual fields.

Comment: Oh... I might have mistook static for final, I completely thought that static fields could'nt be changed... My bad, oh and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `globalTime` in a multi-threading  consider using a static [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html), that will handle synchronization.

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably end up having to use multi-threading so I'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

If your value depends on globalTime, use `static volatile` field as:

```
public class Foo {
    static volatile long globalTime=System.nanoTime();

}
class B{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(Foo.globalTime);
    }
}
```

Since volatile fields avoid compiler caching the values which depends on time fields.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943472/1291122) SO answer would further help you.

Comment: What's the differnce between a `static volatile long` and an `static AtomicLong`? (besides one being a primitive type and the other being an actual object). Does one use the other under-the-hood?

Answer (score 0):

Could have it as a static field wrapped around a thread that just keeps calling `System.nanoTime()`. I don't see a problem with that. Something like this

```
    private static long timer = 0;
static {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                timer = System.nanoTime() - timer;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```