# Why do these threads return an incorrect calculation?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, distributed-computing

I am quite new to concurrent programming and I am enjoying it so far :)! However I just realized how tricky concurrent programming.

I have multiple threads which perform their own computations. Each thread operates on a certain variable and returns a result, however the result returned is incorrect.

This class performs the thread calculations:

```
public class SharedDataThread extends Thread {

private SharedData mySharedData;
private String myThreadName;
private static long testVariable = 0;

// Setup the thread

SharedDataThread(String name, SharedData sharedstuff) {
    super(name);
    mySharedData = sharedstuff;
    myThreadName = name;
}


public void run() {

    System.out.println(myThreadName + " is running");
    Thread me = Thread.currentThread(); // get a ref to the current thread

    if (me.getName() == "myThread1") {
        try {
            sleep(2000);

            mySharedData.acquireLock();
            System.out.println(me.getName()
                    + " is performing computations!");

            testVariable = testVariable + 20;
            testVariable = testVariable * 5;
            testVariable = testVariable / 3;

            System.out.println(me.getName() + " modified the value to : "
                    + testVariable + "\n");

            sleep(2000);
            mySharedData.releaseLock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to get lock when reading:" + e);
        }
    } else if (me.getName() == "myThread2") {
        try {
            sleep(2000);

            mySharedData.acquireLock();
            System.out.println(myThreadName
                    + " is performing computations!");

            testVariable = testVariable - 5;
            testVariable = testVariable * 10;
            testVariable = (long) (testVariable / 2.5);

            System.out.println(me.getName() + " modified the value to : "
                    + testVariable + "\n");

            sleep(2000);
            mySharedData.releaseLock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to get lock when reading:" + e);
        }
    } else if (me.getName() == "myThread3") {
        try {
            sleep(2000);

            mySharedData.acquireLock();

            System.out.println(me.getName()
                    + " is performing computations!");

            testVariable = testVariable - 50;
            testVariable = testVariable / 2;
            testVariable = testVariable * 33;

            System.out.println(me.getName() + " modified the value to : "
                    + testVariable + "\n");

            sleep(2000);
            mySharedData.releaseLock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to get lock when reading:" + e);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            sleep(2000);

            mySharedData.acquireLock();
            System.out.println(me.getName()
                    + " is performing computations!");

            testVariable = testVariable * 20;
            testVariable = testVariable / 10;
            testVariable = testVariable - 1;

            System.out.println(me.getName() + " modified the value to : "
                    + testVariable + "\n");

            sleep(2000);

            mySharedData.releaseLock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to get lock when reading:" + e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The final result of the variable is "
            + testVariable);
}
```

}

The threads are executed in another class with its own main thread of execution:

```
public class SharingExample {
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
SharedData mySharedData = new SharedData();


SharedDataThread myThread1 = new SharedDataThread("myThread1", mySharedData);
SharedDataThread myThread2 = new SharedDataThread("myThread2", mySharedData);
SharedDataThread myThread3 = new SharedDataThread("myThread3", mySharedData);
SharedDataThread myThread4 = new SharedDataThread("myThread4", mySharedData);


// Now start the threads executing

myThread1.start();
myThread2.start();
myThread3.start();
myThread4.start();
```

}
}

the SharedData class is just a class for implementing locks and such.

```
public class SharedData {

  private boolean accessing=false; // true a thread has a lock, false otherwise
  private int threadsWaiting=0; // number of waiting writers

  // attempt to acquire a lock
  public synchronized void acquireLock() throws InterruptedException{
  Thread me = Thread.currentThread(); // get a ref to the current thread
  System.out.println(me.getName()+" is attempting to acquire a lock!");

  ++threadsWaiting;
    while (accessing) {  // while someone else is accessing or threadsWaiting > 0
      System.out.println(me.getName()+" waiting to get a lock as someone else is accessing...");
      //wait for the lock to be released - see releaseLock() below
     wait();
    }
    // nobody has got a lock so get one
    --threadsWaiting;
    accessing = true;
    System.out.println(me.getName()+" got a lock!"); 
  }

  // Releases a lock to when a thread is finished

  public synchronized void releaseLock() {
      //release the lock and tell everyone
      accessing = false;
      notifyAll();
      Thread me = Thread.currentThread(); // get a ref to the current thread
      System.out.println(me.getName()+" released a lock!");
  }

}
```

Where is the problem here?

Comment: Is `testVariable` supposed to be shared across all threads, or each thread should be doing calculation with their own `testVariable`?

Comment: Show `SharedData` so that we know how the locks are implemented. Also, what is the wrong output, and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: That is correct, I made testVariable static for the purpose that it can be shared amongst the threads and each perform a calculation on   that testVariable.

Comment: You could have made this code a *lot* simpler. If you're struggling with a problem, why have all those irrelevant complications?

Comment: Well, when myThread3 first makes its own calculation, it returns a value of -1, even though it is supposed to be -825

Comment: The whole point of a program like this is that the output is unpredictable, because you don't know what order the various operations will be performed in, and those operations are not commutative.  I'd say your program is working correctly; although you haven't really specified what "correctly" would be.

Comment: I couldn't find an error but how can you guarantee the result.
Maybe Thread 3 executed first so the calculation changes..

Comment: Yes  that is correct, there is no order for those operations and that is intended. But the calculations performed on testVariable returns a wrong number which I mentioned above with myThread 3 running first and setting testVariable to -1 instead of -825 if it is run first.

Comment: Why do you think thread 3 ran first?

Comment: Oh wow I think I found the problem, in debug mode, the first thread switches to the "else" part in the else if chain statement even though it is supposed to execute the first chain in the if statement. EDIT: I just modified the last branch of the else into an else-if, and nothing was running at all. I think I should just make these 4 threads have their own classes and each run their run functions. EDIT 2: Thread 3 randomly ran first, but executed the "else" statement, which is not intended.

Comment: ^ Thank you :), I used equals() method instead of '==' and it works as intended .

Answer (score 1):

Your 'testVariable' should be marked as 'volatile'. See this topic for more information: [Volatile Vs Static in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java).

Comment: This is not correct. There is a *happens-before* edge induced by the `acquireLock`-`relaseLock` methods.