# while loop without body is falling into a infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop, runnable

I have searched a lot but didn't find solution of this problem so I asked the question here.

I made a small chunk of code to replicate the problem.
so following are those Java classes.

The class with the main function:

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Background ob = new Background();

        while(ob.val > 0);

        System.out.println("Program Completed");
    }
}
```

The runnable class:

```
package test;

public class Background implements Runnable {
    int val;
    Thread t;

    public Background() {
        val = 500;
        t=new Thread(this); 
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(val > -1000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            val--;
        }
    }

}
```

Now this code is not printing "Program Completed", so I'm thinking that the while loop is in infinite loop.
But if I replace `while(ob.val > 0);` with

```
while(ob.val > 0){
    System.out.println("val: "+ob.val);
};
```

or any `System.out.println()` statement then I can see "Program Completed".
But yes only any `System.out.println()` statement.
If I replace `while(ob.val > 0);` with

```
int g;
while(ob.val > 0){
    g = 0;
};
```

Above code also not showing "Program Completed".

The main code is too large to post here so I have replicated the problem. 
Tested th replicated code in ubuntu 14.04, 
JDK -> jdk-8u31-linux-x64

I didnt tested this replicated code in Windows. But I tested the main code in windows & its working fine.

I'm really confused with this type of behavior. Will any one help me??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no synchronisation on accesses to `val`.

Comment: So will I just use a semaphore variable or I have to do anything else?

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal Just delcare `val` to be `volatile`

Comment: why not just use a global flag that you can set in your runnable that will indicate that it is done, then put while(!done); instead of while(ob.val > 0); since you have not access to ob.val

Comment: @faljbour - he has access to ob.val, if it class variable is not specified by private/protected/public, it is accessible in its package.

Comment: @faljbour The same issue should happen with `boolean` variables. He would still need some form of synchronization.

Comment: yes mr. @faljbour I already done it in my main code what you said. But I was very curious to know why its happening.

Comment: Mr. @Jeffrey I will do what you have said.

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal You might want to take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12193970/758280) for an explanation of what `volatile` does.

Comment: Mr. @Jeffrey I read it and working now. But I want to know if I don't make that val to be volatile then how by adding a simple system.out.println() under the while solving the issue?

Comment: `System.out.println` is a synchronised method; that's why.

Comment: but in windows only while(ob.val > 0); is working. why?

Comment: @I.K. I dont think that the method System.out.println() is sysnchronised it uses synchronised block inside public void println(String x) {
        synchronized (this) {
            print(x);
            newLine();
        }
    }