# Does Java volatile read flush writes, and does volatile write update reads

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand read-acquire(does not reorder with subsequent read/write operations after it), and write-release(does not reorder with read/write operations preceding it).
My q is:-

1. In case of read-acquire, do the writes preceding it get flushed?
2. In case of write-release, do the previous reads get updated?

Also, is read-acquire same as volatile read, and write release same as volatile write in Java?

Why this is important is that, let's take case of write-release..

```
y = x; // a read.. let's say x is 1 at this point
System.out.println(y);// 1 printed
//or you can also consider System.out.println(x);
write_release_barrier();
//somewhere here, some thread sets x = 2
ready = true;// this is volatile
System.out.println(y);// or maybe, println(x).. what will be printed?
```

At this point, is x 2 or 1?
Here, consider ready to be volatile.
I understand that all stores before volatile will first be made visible.. and then only the volatile will be made visible. Thanks.

Ref:- http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No: not all writes are flushed, nor are all reads updated.

Java works on a "happens-before" basis for multithreading. Basically, if A happens-before B, and B happens-before C, then A happens-before C. So your question amounts to whether `x=2` formally happens-before some action that reads x.

Happens-before edges are basically established by synchronizes-with relationships, which are defined in [JLS 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4). There are a few different ways to do this, but for volatiles, it's basically amounts to a write to volatile happening-before a read to that same volatile:

> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) *synchronizes-with* all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

Given that, if your thread writes `ready = true`, then that write alone doesn't mean *anything* happens-before it (as far as that write is concerned). It's actually the opposite; that write to `ready` happens-before things on other threads, iff they read `ready`.

So, if the other thread (that sets `x = 2`) had written to ready *after* it set `x = 2`, and this thread (that you posted above) *then* read `ready`, then it would see `x = 2`. That is because the write happens-before the read, and the reading thread therefore sees everything that the writing thread had done (up to and including the write). Otherwise, you have a data race, and basically all bets are off.

A couple additional notes:

- If you don't have a happens-before edge, you *may* still see the update; it's just that you're not guaranteed to. So, don't assume that if you don't read a write to `ready`, then you'll still see x=1. You might see x=1, or x=2, or possibly some other write (up to and including the default value of x=0)
- In your example, `y` is always going to be 1, because you don't re-read `x` after the "somewhere here" comment. For purposes of this answer, I've assumed that there's a second `y=x` line immediately before or after `ready = true`. If there's not, then y's value will be unchanged from what it was in the first `println`, (assuming no other thread directly changes it -- which is guaranteed if it's a local variable), because actions within a thread always appear as if they are not reordered.

Answer (score 7):

The Java memory model is not specified in terms of "read-acquire" and "write-release".  These terms / concepts come from other contexts, and as the article you referenced makes abundantly clear, they are often used (by different experts) to mean different things.

If you want to understand how volatiles work in Java, you need to understand the Java memory model and the Java terminology ... which is (fortunately) well-founded and precisely specified<sup>1</sup>.  Trying to map the Java memory model onto "read-acquire" and "write-release" semantics is a bad idea because:

- "read-acquire" and "write-release" terminology and semantics are not well specified, and
- a hypothetical JMM -> "read-acquire" / "write-release" semantic mapping is only one possible implementation of the JMM.  Others mappings may exist *with different, and equally valid semantics*.

---

<sup>1 - ... modulo that experts have noted flaws in some versions of the JMM.  But the point is that a serious attempt has been made to provide a theoretically sound specification ... as part of the Java Language Specification.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

No, reading a volatile variable will not flush preceding writes. Visible actions will ensure that preceding actions are visible, but reading a volatile variable is not visible to other threads.

No, writing to a volatile variable will not clear the cache of previously read values. It is only guaranteed to flush previous writes.

In your example, clearly `y` will still be 1 on the last line. Only one assignment has been made to `y`, and that was 1, according to the preceding output. Perhaps that was a typo, and you meant to write `println(x)`, but even then, the value of 2 is not guaranteed to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st question, answer is that FIFO order

For your 2nd question: pls check  [Volatile Vs Static in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java)