# Incrementing Static variable with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, semaphore

I have a number of Customers each has its own thread. I have a cafe object which contains a semaphore with maximum of 5 permits. Customers arrive and leave at different times, so I need to keep track of time passed, a customer acquires a permit from the semaphore when it arrives and releases it when it leaves.

The customer implements runnable, which calls this below 'eat' method of the cafe. I have tested and my counter is being incremented above the arrival times, yet the try/ catch statement is not getting called.

```
public void eat(Customer customer)
{

    while(true) {

        System.out.println("hello");

        if (customer.getArrivalTime() < Main.counter) {

            try {

                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println(customer.getName() + ' ' + customer.getArrivalTime());
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(customer.getLeavetime());
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                iex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //System.out.printf("Farmer %s has crossed the bridge.\n",customer.getName());
                semaphore.release();
                System.out.println(Main.counter);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant snippet of Customer Class

```
public class Customer implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
            icecream.eat(this);

}
```

Relevant snippet of main

```
 public class Main {

    static int counter = 0;
    static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create timer task to increment counter
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // System.out.println("TimerTask executing counter is: " + counter);
            counter++;
        }
    };

    Customer c1 = new Customer(Parlor, 5); //arrival time of 5
    Thread t1 = new Thread(c1);
    timer = new Timer("MyTimer");//create a new timer
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //start timer to increment  counter
    t1.start();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: without seeing Customer and Main implementation it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: When the try catch block isn't called I would assume that customer.getArrivalTime() < Main.counter is false?

Comment: `if (customer.getArrivalTime() < Main.counter)` -- What does that mean?

Comment: @PaulWasilewski yes you would assume that is the case, but counter is being incremented and get higher than customer.getArrivalTime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes of the `counter` variable are not visible to all threads. To make sure that all threads reading the same `counter` value you have to use  `volatile`.

```
static volatile int counter = 0;
```

More information see [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) and [static vs. volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java).