# Thread class's volatile variable does not update its value but static does

Tags: java, multithreading

In below code I am trying to use multiple threads to access queue until `isFound = false`. I have declared `isFound` variable as `volatile` and I am changing its value to true after some condition. If I change its value in one thread and by definition its updated value should be visible to all other threads. When I run this code, the value of `isFound` is still `false`.

If I change isFound from volatile to static it works fine why is that?

```
class FileAccessThread implements Runnable {

    volatile  boolean isFound = false;
    BlockingQueue<String> bq;
        public FileAccessThread(BlockingQueue<String> bq) {
        this.bq = bq;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ifFound "+isFound);
        if(bq !=null && !isFound){
            try {
                System.out.println("Current Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                String filePath = bq.take();
                System.out.println("File Path "+filePath);
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                if(filePath.equals("c:/test/t5.txt")) {
                    isFound = true;
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MultiFileAccess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        BlockingQueue<String> bq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        bq.add("c:/test/t1.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t2.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t3.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t4.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t5.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t6.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t7.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t8.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t9.txt");
        bq.add("c:/test/t10.txt");

        int lengthOfQueue = bq.size();

        for(int i=0;i < lengthOfQueue-1;i++){
            e.execute(new FileAccessThread(bq));
        }

        e.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 10 different FileAccessThread object, each with its own isFound variable. Unless you make it static. You should probably read about the fundamentals of the language....

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is very poor design, you should make it `static volatile` if you want the current design to *always* work.

Comment: I understand that there will be only one copy of static variable for all the objects but my question is why volatile will not work in this case ?

Comment: if it's static volatile, it will work. If it's just volatile, then each thread has it's own copy, so the other threads never see when it gets set.

Comment: If I am not wrong Volatile is not cached , the value is updated on main memory so that other threads can see it. But according to you "thread has it's own copy, so the other threads never see when it gets set" how does this applies ?

Comment: @MadhuCM In your code, there are 10 volatile variables. Let's call them v1, v2, ..., v10. When Thread 1 sets v1 to true and Thread 3 checks v3, it reads false, because they are not the same variable. Volatile has nothing to do with this.

Comment: A good explanation as to why one could need the volatile keyword: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what `static` and `volatile` do.

`volatile` imposes a set of memory read/write semantics on the variable. In this case, it doesn't matter, because you've defined each thread with it's own variable, so each thread only reads and writes it's own, local copy of `isFound`.

In the case where you've defined it as static, then all of the threads are sharing the same variable - so if one thread changes it, then the other threads will (likely) see it. You don't have any synchronization around the variable though, so it's non-deterministic as to when or which threads will see the change.

For a more in-depth look at static vs volatile, look at the answer to this question: [Volatile Vs Static in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java)

Comment: "its own copy of the variable" is a bit confusing - each thread has its own variable, which is not a copy of anything.

Comment: removed 'copy' wording.

Answer (score 0):

Just change how you instantiate your `Runnable`:

```
Runnable oneInstanceOnly = new FileAccessThread(bq);
for(int i=0;i < lengthOfQueue-1;i++){
    e.execute(oneInstanceOnly);
}
```

You created many instances, each having its own `isFound` field, unless created as a `static`.