# How a thread can see stale reference of safely initialized object

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have been trying to figure out that how immutable objects which are safely published could be observed with stale reference.

```
public final class Helper {
private final int n;

  public Helper(int n) {
    this.n = n;
  }
} 

class Foo {
  private Helper helper;

  public Helper getHelper() {
    return helper;
  }

  public void setHelper(int num) {
    helper = new Helper(num);
  }
}
```

So far I could understand that Helper is immutable and can be safely published. A reading thread either reads null or fully initialized Helper object as it won't be available until fully constructed. The solution is to put volatile in Foo class which I don't understand.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. `helper` is not safely published. So, you need to publish it safely.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java before?

Comment: @AndyTurner Do I interpret the statement incorrect that immutable objects can be safely published without additional synchronization?

Comment: @RubaMushtaq you don't publish objects, you publish references to objects. It's irrelevant whether the object is safely initialized if the reference you are handing out is not up-to-date.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for mentioning the update references.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are publishing a reference to an immutable object is irrelevant here.

If you are reading the value of a reference from multiple threads, you need to ensure that the write *happens before* a read if you care about all threads using the most up-to-date value.

*Happens before* is a precisely-defined term in the language spec, specifically the part about the Java Memory Model, which allows threads to make optimisations for example by not always updating things in main memory (which is slow), instead holding them in their local cache (which is much faster, but can lead to threads holding different values for the "same" variable). Happens-before is a relation that helps you to reason about how multiple threads interact when using these optimisations.

Unless you actually create a happens-before relationship, there is no guarantee that you will see the most recent value. In the code you have shown, there is no such relationship between writes and reads of `helper`, so your threads are not guaranteed to see "new" values of `helper`. They *might*, but they likely won't.

The easiest way to make sure that the write happens  before the read would be to make the `helper` member variable `final`: the writes to values of `final` fields are guaranteed to happen before the end of the constructor, so all threads always see the correct value of the field (provided `this` wasn't leaked in the constructor).

Making it `final` isn't an option here, apparently, because you have a setter. So you have to employ some other mechanism.

Taking the code at face value, the simplest option would be to use a (final) `AtomicInteger` instead of the `Helper` class: writes to `AtomicInteger` are guaranteed to happen before subsequent reads. But I guess your actual helper class is probably more complicated.

So, you have to create that happens-before relationship yourself. Three mechanisms for this are:

- Using `AtomicReference<Helper>`: this has similar semantics to `AtomicInteger`, but allows you to store a reference-typed value. (Thanks for pointing this out, @Thilo).
- Making the field `volatile`: this guarantees visibility of the most recently-written value, because it causes writes to flush to main memory (as opposed to reading from a thread's cache), and reads to read from main memory. It effectively stops the JVM making this particular optimization.
- Accessing the field in a synchronized block. The easiest thing to do would be to make the getter and setter methods synchronized. Significantly, you should not synchronize on `helper`, since this field is being changed.

Comment: Maybe a third option could be `AtomicReference<Helper>`. Same reasoning as for `AtomicInteger` (but for the case that `Helper` is indeed necessary).

Comment: @AndyTurner Can I say this that an object which is safely published should be constructed properly by proper mechanism ,i:e final or synchronization otherwise it can have stale data.

Answer (score 1):

Cite from [Volatile vs Static in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423622/volatile-vs-static-in-java)

> This means that if two threads update a variable of the same Object concurrently, and the variable is not declared volatile, there could be a case in which one of the thread has in cache an old value.

Given your code, the following can happen:

- Thread 1 calls getHelper() and gets null
- Thread 2 calls getHelper() and gets null
- Thread 1 calls setHelper(42)
- Thread 2 calls setHelper(24)

And in this case your trouble starts regarding which Helper object will be used in which thread. The keyword `volatile` will at least solve the caching problem.

Comment: That means it was an issue of caching not partially initialized objects. An objects would always be initialized safely in this case but the reference can be stale.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `helper` is being read by multiple threads simultaneously. At the least, you have to make it `volatile` or the compiler will begin caching it in registers local to threads and any updates to the variable may not reflect in the main memory. Using `volatile`, when a thread starts reading a shared variable, it will clear its cache and fetch a fresh value from the global memory. When it finishes reading it, it will flush the contents of its cache into the main memory so that other threads may get the updated value.